# How to implement folding with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have an almost working solution.  However, it fails to compile some simple cases, and I can't decipher the error message.

My current solution:

```
#define AUTO_RETURN( EXPR ) -> decltype( EXPR ) \
{ return EXPR; }

template< typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename Second >
auto foldl( BinaryFunc&& func, First&& first, Second&& second )
AUTO_RETURN( func( std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second) ) )

template<typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest >
auto foldl( BinaryFunc&& func, First&& first, Second&& second, Rest&&... rest )
AUTO_RETURN(
   foldl(
      std::forward<BinaryFunc>(func),
      func( std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second) ),
      std::forward<Rest>(rest)... )
   )
```

This [works as expected](http://ideone.com/xRgrj):

```
struct adder
{
   template< int LHS, int RHS >
   std::integral_constant<int,LHS+RHS>
   operator()( std::integral_constant<int,LHS>, std::integral_constant<int,RHS> )
   {
      return {};
   }
};

auto result = foldl( adder(),
      std::integral_constant<int,19>{},
      std::integral_constant<int,23>{}
   );

assert( result.value == 42 );
```

However this [fails to compile](http://ideone.com/pRiBK).

```
foldl( adder(),
      std::integral_constant<int,1>{},
      std::integral_constant<int,2>{},
      std::integral_constant<int,3>{},
      std::integral_constant<int,4>{},
   );
```

Oddly, if I remove all `std::forward` and rvalue refs from the code it [works fine](http://ideone.com/P7VyS).

What am I doing wrong?
Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Some of your code at ideone is missing `#include <cassert>`.

Comment: I think only `std::forward<Rest>(rest)...` is failing, the rest looks fine.

Comment: @ildjarn, why would `std::forward<Rest>(rest)...` fail?

Comment: This reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744400/decltype-with-a-variadic-template-function It's possibly the same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `decltype` in the return type of the variadic `foldl` cannot see the variadic `foldl`, as it hasn't been fully declared yet, so it cannot recurse to another instantiation of itself.

You can do it with a helper `struct`:

```
template<typename BinaryFunc, typename... Args >
struct folder;

template<typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename Second>
struct folder<BinaryFunc,First,Second>
{
    static auto foldl( BinaryFunc&& func, First&& first, Second&& second )
        AUTO_RETURN( func( std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second) ) )
};

template<typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest >
struct folder<BinaryFunc,First,Second,Rest...>
{
    static auto foldl(BinaryFunc&& func, First&& first, Second&& second, Rest&&... rest )
        AUTO_RETURN(
            (folder<
            BinaryFunc,
             decltype(func( std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second) )),Rest...>::
            foldl(
                std::forward<BinaryFunc>(func),
                func( std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second) ),
                std::forward<Rest>(rest)... )
                ))
};

template< typename BinaryFunc, typename... Args >
auto foldl( BinaryFunc&& func, Args&& ... args )
AUTO_RETURN(
    (folder<BinaryFunc,Args...>::foldl(
      std::forward<BinaryFunc>(func),
      std::forward<Args>(args)... ))
   )
```

Comment: So, is it not a compiler bug but really a restriction in the C++11 standard? Could you please tell where to look for it in the text of the standard?

Comment: I believe so. I cannot find anywhere that says the name of the function being declared **is** in scope in the trailing return type, so by default I would therefore say that it **isn't** in scope at this point. See 3.3.2p1 --- the declarator of a function includes the trailing return type.

Comment: why did you add use a `Third` template parameter, instead of `First`, `Second`, and `Rest`?

Comment: It was left over from my initial code. It is unnecessary; I've removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for a great question that caused me to look into a few new areas in C++11.

Anthony W. was faster with a solution; but I still want to share mine, which also uses a helper struct (and it's admittedly more verbose). First, let me share a link to a similar question [trailing return type using decltype with a variadic template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744400/decltype-with-a-variadic-template-function); the answers there are based on the same idea of a helper struct, so their authors deserve credit.

The code below is [checked with ideone](http://ideone.com/JWkmBo). Note that it does not use AUTO_RETURN anymore, as the helper struct now takes care of the type.

```
template< typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename... Types >
struct helper;

template< typename BinaryFunc, typename First>
struct helper<BinaryFunc, First> {
    typedef decltype(std::declval<First>()) type;
};

template< typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename Second >
struct helper<BinaryFunc, First, Second> {
    typedef decltype(
        std::declval<BinaryFunc>()( std::declval<First>(), std::declval<Second>() )
    ) type;
};

template< typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest >
struct helper<BinaryFunc, First, Second, Rest...>  {
    typedef typename helper< BinaryFunc,
                             typename helper<BinaryFunc, First, Second>::type,
                             Rest...
                           >::type
                     type;
};

template< typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename Second >
typename helper<BinaryFunc, First, Second>::type
foldl( BinaryFunc&& func, First&& first, Second&& second ) {
    return func( std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second) );
}

template< typename BinaryFunc, typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest >
typename helper<BinaryFunc, First, Second, Rest...>::type
foldl( BinaryFunc&& func, First&& first, Second&& second, Rest&&... rest ) {
   return foldl(
      std::forward<BinaryFunc>(func),
      func( std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second) ),
      std::forward<Rest>(rest)...
   );
}
```