# Need a way to prefix boost::spirit::qi parser with another one

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a lot of rules that look like this:

```
cmd_BC = (dlm > timestamp > dlm > cid > dlm > double_)
         [
             _val = lazy_shared<dc::BoardControl>(_1, _2, _3)
         ];
```

I want to make it more readable, like:

```
cmd_BC = param(timestamp) > param(cid) > param(double_)
```

or even

```
cmd_BC = params(timestamp, cid, double_)
```

As [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe) pointed out, it boils down to having some means to automatically expect the delimiters. What are the options here? Myself, I see three possibilities, all flawed:

1. *Use a macro.* This wouldn't allow for the shorter variadic form.
2. *Write a custom prefix directive.* I don't seem to have enough experience in Spirit's clockwork, but if it's actually not that hard, I will try to.
3. *Write a wrapper function.* I tried to no luck the following code:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   auto param(const T & parser) -> decltype(qi::lit(dlm) > parser)
   {
       return qi::lit(dlm) > parser;
   }
   ```

   but it doesn't compile, failing at

   ```
       // report invalid argument not found (N is out of bounds)
       BOOST_SPIRIT_ASSERT_MSG(
           (N < sequence_size::value),
           index_is_out_of_bounds, ());
   ```

   I also tried to `return (...).alias()`, but it didn't compile too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is not very "spirit-y" and unfortunately "requires C++11" (I'm not sure how to get the required result type in c++03) but it seems to work. Inspired by the example [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auto.html).

PS: Oh I didn't see your edit. You have almost the same example.

Update: Added another test using a semantic action with _1,_2 and _3
Update2: Changed the signature of operator() and operator[] following vines's advice in the comments.

Update 3: Added a variadic operator() that constructs a combined parser, and removed operator[] after finding a better solution with boost::proto. Changed slightly the examples.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace proto = boost::proto;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
using namespace boost::proto;

//This is a proto grammar/transform that creates the prefixed parser. The parser created depends on the parser passed (if it's a kleene or not)
// in _make_xxx  "_" corresponds to the supplied parser and "_state" to the delimiter
struct CreatePrefixedParser: //you can use _make_greater instead of _make_shift_right if you want to use "expectation"
or_ <
    when < dereference<_>, //If it's a kleene parser...
        _make_shift_right ( //create the parser -> dlm >> *(parser -dlm)
            _state,
            _make_dereference (
                _make_minus ( _child_c<0> ( _ ),
                    _state ) ) ) > ,
    when < unary_plus<_>, //If it's a +parser
        _make_shift_right ( //create the parser -> dlm >> +(parser -dlm)
            _state,
            _make_unary_plus (
                _make_minus ( _child_c<0> ( _ ),
                    _state ) ) ) > ,
    otherwise < //if it's any other parser
        _make_shift_right ( //create the parser -> dlm >> (parser -dlm)
            _state,
            _make_minus ( _,
                _state ) ) >
> {};

//-------------------------------------------------------------
//this combines the parsers this way: parser1, parser2, parser3, parser4 -> parser1>>(parser2 >>(parser3 >> parser4)))
//you can use make_expr<tag::greater> if you want to use "expectation"
//I have absolutely no idea when "deep_copy" is required but it seems to work this way
template<typename Delim, typename First, typename ... Rest>
struct myparser
{
    static auto combine ( Delim dlm_, const First& first, const Rest&...rest ) ->
    decltype ( make_expr<tag::shift_right> ( CreatePrefixedParser() ( deep_copy ( first ), dlm_ ), myparser<Delim, Rest...>::combine ( dlm_, rest... ) ) )
    {
        return make_expr<tag::shift_right> ( CreatePrefixedParser() ( deep_copy ( first ), dlm_ ), myparser<Delim, Rest...>::combine ( dlm_, rest... ) );
    }

};

template<typename Delim, typename Last>
struct myparser<Delim, Last>
{

    static auto combine ( Delim dlm_, const Last& last ) -> decltype ( CreatePrefixedParser() ( deep_copy ( last ), dlm_ ) )
    {
        return CreatePrefixedParser() ( deep_copy ( last ), dlm_ );
    }
};
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T>
struct prefixer
{
    T dlm_;
    prefixer ( T dlm ) : dlm_ ( dlm ) {}

    template <typename ... Args>
    auto operator() ( const Args&... args ) ->
    decltype ( deep_copy ( myparser<T, Args...>::combine ( dlm_, args... ) ) )
    {
        return deep_copy ( myparser<T, Args...>::combine ( dlm_, args... ) );
    }
};
template <typename T>
prefixer<T> make_prefixer ( T dlm )
{
    return prefixer<T> ( dlm );
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "lameducklamedog";

    std::string::const_iterator f ( test.begin() ), l ( test.end() );

    auto param = make_prefixer ( qi::lit ( "lame" ) );
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator> dog = qi::lit ( "do" ) > qi::char_ ( 'g' );
    //qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator> duck = qi::lit ( "duck" ) | qi::int_;
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,std::string()> quackdog = (param (*qi::alpha)  >> param( dog ));


     std::string what;
     if ( qi::parse ( f, l, quackdog, what ) && f == l )
         std::cout << "the duck and the dog are lame, specially the " << what  << std::endl;
     else
         std::cerr << "Uhoh\n" << std::string(f,l) << std::endl;

    test = "*-*2.34*-*10*-*0.16*-*12.5";
    std::string::const_iterator f2 ( test.begin() ), l2 ( test.end() );

    auto param2 = make_prefixer ( qi::lit ( "*-*" ) );
    double d;
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator> myrule = ( param2 ( qi::double_, qi::int_, qi::double_ , qi::double_) ) [phx::ref ( d ) = qi::_1 + qi::_2 + qi::_3 + qi::_4];

    if ( qi::parse ( f2, l2, myrule ) && f2 == l2 )
        std::cout << "the sum of the numbers is " << d << std::endl;
    else
        std::cerr << "Uhoh\n";

}
```

Comment: I've just started to dig into boost::proto docs, when I saw your answer :) Yeah, the idea is similar - to make a parser combinator function. With your code I get the same assert as mine `(argument not found (N is out of bounds))`, I suppose it's related to attribute placeholders being used. When I try `param(double)[val_ = 1_ ]`, it compiles, but segfaults sporadically.

Comment: @vines Do my (stupidly simple) rules cause your compiler error? or the error occurs when you input yours? If it's the latter, could you write your rules so I can try to troubleshoot them?

Comment: The real problem is assigning to the rules, unrelated to the attributes. In my limited testing I only used `param` directly in `qi::parse` where it works, but I can't use `param` in a rule definition.

Comment: Where were my eyes! I've just understood what I actually wrote: `param(a) > param(b)[ val_ = _2 ]`, no surprise it didn't work! And yes, you're right, rules are uncopyable in c++ sense, I changed `prefixer` to `auto operator() (const U & parser )` and it finally works! Thank you. I'll try now to make it variadic.

Comment: @vines Implemented variadic operator (). I have again missed your update.

Comment: I guess that's much more 'spirity' way than mine now :) And @sehe says such a thing would fit into the spirit repository. Maybe propose it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to *automatically* expect or ignore the delimiter expression (`dlm`)?

#### Skippers

This is the classic terrain for Skippers in Spirit. This is especially useful if the delimiter is variable, e.g. whitespace (varying amounts of whitespace acceptable);

```
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
      first, last,                // input iterators
      timestamp > cid > double_,  // just specify the expected params
      qi::space);                 // delimiter, e.g. any amount of whitespace
```

Note the use of `phrase_parse` to enable grammars with skippers.

#### Delimited with `%` parser directive

You could explicitely go and delimit the grammar:

```
 dlm     = qi::lit(','); // as an example, delimit by single comma
 rule    = timestamp > dlm > cid > dlm > double_;
```

This is tedious. Something that might work about nicely for you (depending on the amount of input validation that should be performed:

```
 dlm     = qi::lit(','); // as an example, delimit by single comma
 rule    = (timestamp | cid | double_) % dlm;
```

(This would result in a vector of `variant<timestampt_t, cid_t, double>`)

#### Roll your own

You could roll your own parser directive, similar to [`karma::delimit`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/directive/delimit.html), but for input.

The idea is outlined in this documentation article by Hartmut Kaiser:

- [Creating Your Own Generator Component for Spirit.Karma](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/karma-examples/creating-your-own-generator-component-for-spirit-karma/)

If you're interested, I could see whether I could make this work as an example (I've not used this before). To be honest, I'm surprised something like this doesn't yet exist, and ***I think it would be a prime candidate for the [Spirit Repository](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/index.html)***

Comment: Oh, thanks! That are exactly the words I couldn't formulate: *to automatically expect the delimiters*. Also, I'm curious about why did you prefer the permutation operator over alternative? (That solution looks really pretty, but, if I get it right, allows for permutations of parameters, which is unacceptable unless it will fail at least at some point later - in the variant cast, for example).

Comment: @vines To bo honest, I don't remember why I put the permutation in there. I was probably confusing with the skipper-based approach, in which case `a ^ b ^ c` might have been a succinct way to achieve what you wanted. Feel free to forget about it. I will edit the answer to use `|` instead to avoid the confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I'm finally satisfied with. It's based on these three answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12679189/396583
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6069950/396583
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744742/396583

I've decided not to make it accept arbitrary binary functors though, since I doubt it would have any real-world purpose in context of parsing. So,

```
#include <boost/proto/deep_copy.hpp>

template <typename D>
struct prefixer
{
    template<typename... T>
    struct TypeOfPrefixedExpr;

    template<typename T>
    struct TypeOfPrefixedExpr<T>
    {
        typedef typename boost::proto::result_of::deep_copy
                 < decltype ( std::declval<D>() > std::declval<T>() ) >::type  type;
    };

    template<typename T, typename... P>
    struct TypeOfPrefixedExpr<T, P...>
    {
        typedef typename boost::proto::result_of::deep_copy
                 < decltype ( std::declval<D>() > std::declval<T>()
                              > std::declval<typename TypeOfPrefixedExpr<P...>::type>() ) >::type  type;
    };



    D dlm_;
    prefixer ( D && dlm ) : dlm_ ( dlm ) {}

    template <typename U>
    typename TypeOfPrefixedExpr<U>::type operator() (U && parser )
    {
        return boost::proto::deep_copy ( dlm_ > parser );
    }

    template <typename U, typename ... Tail>
    typename TypeOfPrefixedExpr<U, Tail...>::type
            operator() (U && parser, Tail && ... tail )
    {
        return boost::proto::deep_copy ( dlm_ > parser > (*this)(tail ...) );
    }
};

template <typename D>
prefixer<D> make_prefixer ( D && dlm )
{
    return prefixer<D> ( std::forward<D>(dlm) );
}
```

And it's used like this:

```
auto params = make_prefixer(qi::lit(dlm));

cmd_ID      = params(string) [ _val = lazy_shared<dc::Auth>   (_1) ];

cmd_NAV     = params(timestamp, double_, double_, double_, double_, double_)
              [
                  _val = lazy_shared<dc::Navigation>( _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6 )
              ];

cmd_BC      = params(timestamp, cid, double_)
              [
                  _val = lazy_shared<dc::BoardControl>(_1, _2, _3)
              ];
```

Comment: You should probably accept this answer. Unlike mine it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @llonesmiz I did hesitate a bit back then and decided not to do so: I didn't really produce much new value here, but just aggregated several others' findings. The most important one (deep_copy) is yours.