# Why is the sum 0?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, variadic-templates

I am trying to create a general sum function template. This template will be `left associative`. Below is my implementation

```
    int result=0;
template <typename D, typename T>
const T &sum_helper(const D &d, const T &v) {
    result=result+v;
    return result;
}
int pass(...){}

template <typename D, typename T1, typename... Ts>
auto sum_helper(const D &d, const T1 &v1, const Ts &... params) -> decltype(v1 + sum_helper(d, params...)) {
    return v1 + sum_helper(d, params... );
}

class A {};

template <typename... Ns> 
struct seq {};

template <typename... Ts>
auto sum(const Ts &... params) -> decltype(sum_helper(A(), params...)) 
{
    return  pass((sum_helper(seq<Ts...>(),params)) ...,1);

}
```

But when I call it like `sum(1,2,3,4)` it outputs `0` always. Whats wrong? I know that `pass` should be corrected. But what is the way to correct it?

Comment: What are pass/seq for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original answer doesn't work, because the trailing return type uses an overload prior to its point of declaration.  It's impossible to forward declare a function before knowing its return type, also.  So we need a helper struct.  Here's the (unfortunately now very complicated) version that **works**:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename...>
struct sum_impl;

/* This is the base case */
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct sum_impl<T1, T2>
{
    typedef decltype(std::declval<const T1&>() + std::declval<const T2&>()) result_type;

    static result_type doit(const T1& v1, const T2& v2)
    {
        return v1 + v2;
    }
};

/* And here is the recursive definition for left-associativity */
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
struct sum_impl<T1, T2, Ts...>
{
    typedef decltype(std::declval<const T1&>() + std::declval<const T2&>()) step_type;
    typedef typename sum_impl<step_type, Ts...>::result_type result_type;

    static result_type doit(const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const Ts&... rest)
    {
        return sum_impl<step_type, Ts...>::doit(v1 + v2, rest...);
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
typename sum_impl<Ts...>::result_type sum(const Ts&... args)
{
    return sum_impl<Ts...>::doit(args...);
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/jMwgLz

---

Here's a version that retains the simplicity of Named's answer but is left associative:

```
/* not really needed, unless someone wants to call sum with only a single argument */
template <typename T>
T sum(const T& v)
{
    return v;
}

/* This is the base case */
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2) -> decltype( v1 + v2 )
{
    return v1 + v2;
}

/* And here is the recursive definition for left-associativity */
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const Ts&... rest) -> decltype( sum(v1 + v2, rest...) )
{
    return sum(v1 + v2, rest... );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks better than mine :P

Comment: @Ben this is awesome! Almost correct.. but if I give more than 4 arguments it seems to fail to compile

Comment: @footy: [I see](http://ideone.com/eBq1Mc), it is because the trailing return type uses recursion, but it's before the point of declaration for the current overload.  Don't the other answers fail similarly?

Comment: And, it looks like someone already figured this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065810/how-to-implement-folding-with-variadic-templates?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T1>
auto _sum(T1 & _ret, const T1 & _t1) -> T1
{
    _ret += _t1;
    return _ret;
}

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
auto _sum(T1 & _ret, const T1 & _t1, const Ts &... params) -> T1 
{
    _ret += _t1;
    return _sum(_ret, params...);
}

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
auto sum(const T1 & _t1, const Ts &... params) -> T1 
{
    T1 ret = _t1;
    return _sum(ret, params...);    
}

int main()
{
    cout << sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain how is this left associative?

Comment: @footy: Because it calculates `1 + (2 + 3 + 4 + 5)`. Be aware that left-associativety does NOT fix the order of evaluation in general.

Comment: I tried the following for objects after overloading + operator. It says `template argument deduction/substitution failed` .. How? I am not able to understand

Comment: 1+(...) is right-associative.  Left-associative would be (...)+5.

Comment: @Rollie I needed left associativi

Comment: Hmmm, that's a bit harder - updated code (assuming Matthias is correct re associativity)

Comment: Did you intend to write `T1 ret = _t1;`?  Because right now the first argument is lost.  Also, it's no longer possible to call `sum(n)` with a single argument.  And while you certainly fixed the associativity, I don't think it needed to be this complex.  See my answer.

Comment: Ok, it did need to be complex, but for an entirely different reason.  I see you sidestepped that by not using the exact return type, which may cause unexpected truncation with e.g. `sum(1, 2, 3.4)`.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I call it like sum(1,2,3,4) it outputs 0 always. Whats wrong?

That is because `pass` is **not returning anything** so what you have here is **Undefined Behavior** since you are flowing out of a non void function with out returning anything.

I don't know why you even needed `pass` here

```
return  pass((sum_helper(seq<Ts...>(),params)) ...,1);
```

---

You can just expand the variadic args and send them directly to `sum_helper`. like this

```
return  sum_helper(seq<Ts...>(),params...);
```

---

---

However a simpler version would be

```
template <typename T>
T sum(const T& v) {
    return v;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2) -> decltype( v1 + v2) {
    return v1 + v2;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const Ts&... rest) -> decltype( v1 + v2 + sum(rest...) ) {
    return v1 + v2 + sum(rest... );
}

int main() {
    cout << sum(1,2,3,4);    
}
```

---

And an even simpler version is provided by Rollie's answer.

Comment: I tried the following for objects after overloading + operator. It says template argument deduction/substitution failed .. How? I am not able to understand

Comment: I think your solution won't work for `sum(1,2,3)`; or any odd number of args; it will go to the variadic sum and call `1+2+sum(3)`, and `sum(3)` is not defined.

Comment: @Rollie Yes. I have fixed it. The reason I chose two args in the long version of sum is because gcc doesn't see to be able to deduct `decltype( v1 + sum(rest...) )` properly for some reason. It matches it when there are two args matched and the rest expanded.

Comment: @footy What kind of error messages? and what kind of objects are you adding?