# Sum helper fails for classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, g++-4.7

I have the following sumhelper written:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2) -> decltype( v1 + v2) {
    return v1 + v2;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const Ts&... rest) -> decltype( v1 + v2 + sum(rest...) ) {
    return v1 + v2 + sum(rest... );
}
```

Here is the CPP file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include "Sum.hpp" 

struct A {
    int x;

    A(const int a) : x(a) { std::cout<<x<<std::endl; };

    A &operator+(const A &tmp) const {
        std::cout<<" + "<<tmp.x<<") ";
    };
};

int main () {
    std::cout<<"sum of 1,2,3,4 is : ";

    auto ans = sum(1,2.2,3,4);

    A a(1);
    A b(2);
    A c(3);

    std::cout<<a.x;
    a+b+c;

    sum(a,b,c); //Here is syntax error

    std::cout<<ans<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I not able to do the sum(a,b,c) ? When I have a+b+c working as demonstrate.

It gives a compile error when I pass objects but not when I pass primitive types

I am not able to understand the error template argument deduction/substitution failed.. how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variation of a variardic `apply_binop` that takes an arbitrary operation as the first argument, and a `sum` wrapper that passes a binary `add` to it.  `apply_binop` is better (and more clearly) known as `foldr` I believe:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

#define RETURNS(x) ->decltype(x) { return (x); }

struct add {
  template<typename T, typename U>
  auto operator()( T&& t, U&& u ) const
    RETURNS( std::forward<T>(t)+std::forward<U>(u) )
};


template<typename Op, typename T0>
auto apply_binop( Op&& op, T0&& t0 )
  RETURNS(std::forward<T0>(t0))

template<typename Op, typename T0, typename T1, typename... Ts>
auto apply_binop( Op&& op, T0&& t0, T1&& t1, Ts&&... ts )
  RETURNS(
    op(
      std::forward<T0>(t0),
      apply_binop(op, std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
    )
  )

template<typename... Ts>
auto sum( Ts&&... ts )
  RETURNS( apply_binop( add(), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... ) )

int main() {
  std::cout << sum(1,2,3,4,5) << "\n";
  std::cout << sum(1) << "\n";
  std::cout << sum(1,2) << "\n";
  std::cout << sum(1,2,3) << "\n";
  std::cout << sum(1,2,3,4) << "\n";
  std::cout << sum(1,2,3,4.7723) << "\n";
}
```

It is `foldr` because it applies the binary operation to the rightmost two, then takes that result and applies it with the 3rd last, etc.  `foldl` does the same starting from the left.

The macro `RETURNS` makes up for the inability for C++ to deduce return types for single line functions (which I believe will be fixed in C++17).  Getting gcc 4.7.2 to accept the above with only two `apply_binop` overrides took a bit of tweaking.

Implementing `foldl` without 3 or more overrides is a tad trickier.

Here is another answer where they discuss better ways to work around this issue:

[How to implement folding with variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065810/how-to-implement-folding-with-variadic-templates?rq=1)

Comment: This just took it to a whole new level :).

Comment: This doesnt seems to work for `sum(a,b,c,d,e,f);` where the arguments are all of the type `struct A` in the question

Comment: @footy Here is a live example: http://ideone.com/BP43E9 note that your `struct A`'s `operator+` does undefined behavior by failing to return from `operator+`.

Answer (score 2):

This is my bad (from previous answer) you should add one more template specialization at the top for a single element. Otherwise `sum(1,2,3)` will not find a match because the first two args will be matched by the variadic one and the other expects two args. There is only one left.

```
template <typename T>
T sum(const T& v) {
    return v;
}
```

---

Here again another problem is your operator+ flows out with out returning anything. Which is **Undefined Behavior**. And if you define it as a member it should be const.

```
struct A {
    int x;
    A(const int a) : x(a) { std::cout<<x<<std::endl; };
    A operator+(const A &a1) const
    {
        return A(a1.x + x);
    }
};
```

---

So your complete program should now look like this

```
template <typename T>
T sum(const T& v) {
    return v;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2) -> decltype( v1 + v2) {
    return v1 + v2;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const Ts&... rest) -> decltype( v1 + v2 + sum(rest...) ) {
    return v1 + v2 + sum(rest... );
}

struct A {
    int x;
    A(const int a) : x(a) { };
    A operator+(const A &a1) const { return A(a1.x + x); }
};

int main () {
    std::cout<<"sum of 1,2.2,3,4 is : ";
    auto ans = sum(1,2.2,3,4);
    cout << ans;


    A a(1); A b(2); A c(3);
    a+b+c;
    auto ans2 = sum(a,b,c);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"sum of A(1),A(2),A(3) is : ";
    std::cout<<ans2.x<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

stdout

```
sum of 1,2.2,3,4 is : 10.2
sum of A(1),A(2),A(3) is : 6
```

Comment: You can do `sum` this with 2 overloads.

Comment: @Yakk That's what I thought but gcc has issues with `decltype( v1 + sum(rest...) )`. Can not deduce the type of `sum(rest...)` with one arg. It works fine if you match two args explicitly like I did. Hold on I will show you what I mean.

Comment: @Yakk Here. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b13ddc636e02fa459d0b82e125b6c820-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59

Comment: Interesting.  It doesn't seem to want to use itself to deduce its own return type?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't seem to recognize the single arg sum when deducting type for `decltype( v1 + sum(rest...) )`. When `rest` is just one arg.

Comment: @Yakk Actually you are right. It doesn't consider **itself**. I did some testing for a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497977/general-min-and-max-auto-return-type

Comment: Oh, and as an aside, you should use  perfect forwarding on `sum`.  Little reason not to.  :)

Comment: This doesnt seems to work for `sum(a,b,c,d,e,f);` where the arguments are all of the type struct `A` in the question.

Comment: @footy It is working for me. I don't why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correct variadic sum

```
#include <iostream>

namespace cs540 {
    template <typename T>
    const T & sum(const T & v) {
        return v;
    }

    template <typename T, typename T2, typename ... Ts>
    T sum(const T & v, const T2 & w, const Ts & ... params) {
        return sum(w+v,params...);
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace cs540;
    using namespace std;
    cout << sum(1.1,2,3,4,6,8,9,1.1) << endl;
}
```

You also need to mark your method operator+  as const

Comment: Here `sum(1,2,3,4.555,6,8,9)` would return an integer val!

Comment: The reason yours isn't working is because you have to mark operator+ as const

Comment: Mine compiles, just so u know ur function is not marked const in ur example

Comment: @aarinman I changed it in the code earlier. Changing it in the example now.