# General min and max - C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Writing a general minimum function, Two questions came to my mind. The code works fine with any input type and different argument number:

```
namespace xyz
{

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto min(const T1 &a, const T2 &b) -> decltype(a+b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Args>
auto min(const T1 &a, const T2 &b, Args ... args) -> decltype(a+b)
{
    return min(min(a, b), args...);
}

}

int main()
{
    cout << xyz::min(4, 5.8f, 3, 1.8, 3, 1.1, 9) << endl;
    //                   ^        ^           ^
    //                   |        |           |
    //                 float    double       int
}
```

- Is there a better replacement for `decltype(a+b)`? I thing there's a standard class which I can't remember, something like `decltype(std::THE_RESULT<a,b>::type)`.
- The returned type of that `decltype(std::THE_RESULT<a,b>::type)`is `const &` or not ?

Comment: It seems odd to me that you allow a and b to be different types.  This opens the door for all sorts of nonsensical comparisons, like `min(42, "three")`.  Why not require both parameters (and the return value) all be of the same type?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: _"For arithmetic types, the common type may also be viewed as the type of the (possibly mixed-mode) arithmetic expression such as T0() + T1() + ... + Tn()"_. So I think, it's prohibited to use `min(42, "three")`. It makes compile error.

Comment: By the way, there's an article on reproducing the good parts of the macro versions using templates. It's surprisingly a lot to do.

Comment: @MM.: Yes, it will get compiler errors for some combinations, but there's also the risk that it'll apply unexpected conversions to one or both of the types to come up with a non-intuitive common type.  Consider a mixed int/float comparison that would return a float.  Some ints can't be exactly represented in a float.  It would be weird for a `min(myint, myfloat)` to return a value that doesn't exactly match one of the parameters.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Almost agree, but we're daily using these conversions for example `myint + myfloat` and it's up to the programmer to handle it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)(`c++11`):

> For non-specialized `std::common_type`, the rules for determining the
>   common type between every pair `T1`, `T2` are exactly the rules for
>   determining the return type of the ternary conditional operator where
>   `T1` and `T2` are the types of its second and the third operands.

and

> For arithmetic types, the common type may also be viewed as the type
>   of the (possibly mixed-mode) arithmetic expression such as `T0() + T1()
>   + ... + Tn().`

Not sure about `const&`, but you could play with [`std::remove_cv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) and [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) (and [`std::is_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference) to find out the answer).

In fact, [here's](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) a list of type support utilities. Knock yourself out.

Comment: Thanks ... I added a third related question. Would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: @MM. That will work but is not completely what you want I think. For `(1,2,1.1)` that will return an `int`. `decltype(min(1, 2))`. You can try to cover the whole thing like `decltype(min(min(a, b), args...))` but that doesn't work with `gcc` right now. I think it is a bug.

Comment: @MM. Also `const Args& ...`. otherwise you will have cv issues.

Answer (score 5):

After the answer and worth comments I did it as below:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto min(const T1 &a, const T2 &b) 
-> typename std::common_type<const T1&, const T2&>::type
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Args>
auto min(const T1 &a, const T2 &b, const Args& ... args)
-> typename std::common_type<const T1&, const T2&, const Args& ...>::type
{
    return min(min(a, b), args...);
}
```