# Implementing variadic min / max functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm implementing variadic min/max functions. A goal is to **take advantage of the compile time known number of arguments and perform an unrolled evaluation** (avoid run-time loops). The current state of the code is as follows (presenting min - max is similar)

```
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T vmin(T val1, T val2)
{
    return val1 < val2 ? val1 : val2;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T vmin(T val1, T val2, Ts&&... vs)
{
    return val1 < val2 ?
        vmin(val1, std::forward<Ts>(vs)...) : 
            vmin(val2, std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
}

int main()
{
    cout << vmin(3, 2, 1, 2, 5) << endl;    
    cout << vmin(3., 1.2, 1.3, 2., 5.2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now [**this works**](http://ideone.com/qlyYbn), but I have some **questions / problems** :

1. The **non variadic overload** has to accept its arguments by value. If I try passing other types of ref I have the following results

   - universal references `&&` -> compilation error
   - const references `const&` -> OK
   - plain references `&` -> compilation error

   Now I know that [function templates mix weirdly with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411782/2567683) but is there any specific know-how for the mix up at hand ? **What type of arguments should I opt for?**
2. Wouldn't the expansion of the parameter pack by sufficient ? Do I really need to forward my arguments to the recursive call ?
3. Is this functionallity better implemented when wrapped inside a struct and exposed as a static member function. Would the ability to partial specialize buy me anything ?
4. Is there a more robust/efficient implementation/design for the function version ? (particullarly I'm wondering whether a `constexpr` version would be a match for the efficiency of template metaprogramming)

Comment: Good question. You can even implement `min` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16498347/952747).

Comment: Why don't you use `std::min` with `std::initializer_list`, i.e. `template <typename ...Args> auto vmin(Args&&... args) { return std::min({ std::forward<Args>(args)... }); }`?

Comment: @nosid Ok valid point, but I'm trying (again it may not have much meaning) to implement a version that would perform compile time unrolling, as opposed to a function that runs a loop at runtime (maybe I should mention that in the question - I just noticed that it's not apparent)

Comment: @nosid I think you should use something like `std::common_type` in your variant.

Comment: Consider implementing along the lines of `vmin(vmin(val1, val2), vs...)`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[live example](http://ideone.com/7dYgS2)

This does perfect forwarding on arguments.  It relies on RVO for return values, as it returns a value type regardless of the input types, because `common_type` does that.

I implemented `common_type` deduction, allowing mixed types to be passed in, and the "expected" result type output.

We support the min of 1 element, because it makes the code slicker.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T vmin(T&&t)
{
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}

template<typename T0, typename T1, typename... Ts>
typename std::common_type<
  T0, T1, Ts...
>::type vmin(T0&& val1, T1&& val2, Ts&&... vs)
{
  if (val2 < val1)
    return vmin(val2, std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
  else
    return vmin(val1, std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
}


int main()
{
  std::cout << vmin(3, 2, 0.9, 2, 5) << std::endl;

  std::cout << vmin(3., 1.2, 1.3, 2., 5.2) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Now, while the above is a perfectly acceptable solution, it isn't ideal.

The expression `((a<b)?a:b) = 7` is legal C++, but `vmin( a, b ) = 7` is not, because `std::common_type` `decay`s is arguments blindly (caused by what I consider an over-reaction to it returning rvalue references when fed two value-types in an older implementation of `std::common_type`).

Simply using `decltype( true?a:b )` is tempting, but it both results in the rvalue reference problem, and does not support `common_type` specializations (as an example, `std::chrono`).  So we both want to use `common_type` and do not want to use it.

Secondly, writing a `min` function that doesn't support unrelated pointers and does not let the user change the comparison function seems wrong.

So what follows is a more complex version of the above.  [live example](https://ideone.com/KEUyqJ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

namespace my_min {

  // a common_type that when fed lvalue references all of the same type, returns an lvalue reference all of the same type
  // however, it is smart enough to also understand common_type specializations.  This works around a quirk
  // in the standard, where (true?x:y) is an lvalue reference, while common_type< X, Y >::type is not.
  template<typename... Ts>
  struct my_common_type;

  template<typename T>
  struct my_common_type<T>{typedef T type;};

  template<typename T0, typename T1, typename... Ts>
  struct my_common_type<T0, T1, Ts...> {
    typedef typename std::common_type<T0, T1>::type std_type;
    // if the types are the same, don't change them, unlike what common_type does:
    typedef typename std::conditional< std::is_same< T0, T1 >::value,
      T0,
    std_type >::type working_type;
    // Careful!  We do NOT want to return an rvalue reference.  Just return T:
    typedef typename std::conditional<
      std::is_rvalue_reference< working_type >::value,
      typename std::decay< working_type >::type,
      working_type
    >::type common_type_for_first_two;
    // TODO: what about Base& and Derived&?  Returning a Base& might be the right thing to do.
    // on the other hand, that encourages silent slicing.  So maybe not.
    typedef typename my_common_type< common_type_for_first_two, Ts... >::type type;
  };
  template<typename... Ts>
  using my_common_type_t = typename my_common_type<Ts...>::type;
  // not that this returns a value type if t is an rvalue:
  template<typename Picker, typename T>
  T pick(Picker&& /*unused*/, T&&t)
  {
    return std::forward<T>(t);
  }
  // slight optimization would be to make Picker be forward-called at the actual 2-arg case, but I don't care:
  template<typename Picker, typename T0, typename T1, typename... Ts>
  my_common_type_t< T0, T1, Ts...> pick(Picker&& picker, T0&& val1, T1&& val2, Ts&&... vs)
  {
    // if picker doesn't prefer 2 over 1, use 1 -- stability!
    if (picker(val2, val1))
      return pick(std::forward<Picker>(pick), val2, std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
    else
      return pick(std::forward<Picker>(pick), val1, std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
  }

  // possibly replace with less<void> in C++1y?
  struct lesser {
    template<typename LHS, typename RHS>
    bool operator()( LHS&& lhs, RHS&& rhs ) const {
      return std::less< typename std::decay<my_common_type_t<LHS, RHS>>::type >()(
          std::forward<LHS>(lhs), std::forward<RHS>(rhs)
      );
    }
  };
  // simply forward to the picked_min function with a smart less than functor
  // note that we support unrelated pointers!
  template<typename... Ts>
  auto min( Ts&&... ts )->decltype( pick( lesser(), std::declval<Ts>()... ) )
  {
    return pick( lesser(), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
  }
}

int main()
{
  int x = 7;
  int y = 3;
  int z = -1;
  my_min::min(x, y, z) = 2;
  std::cout << x << "," << y << "," << z << "\n";
  std::cout << my_min::min(3, 2, 0.9, 2, 5) << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_min::min(3., 1.2, 1.3, 2., 5.2) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The downside to the above implementation is that most classes do not support `operator=(T const&)&&=delete` -- ie, they do not block rvalues from being assigned to, which can lead to surprises if one of the types in the `min` does not .  Fundamental types do.

Which is a side note: start deleting your rvalue reference `operator=`s people.

Comment: Hmm.  Despite naive reading of `common_type` saying `common_type<X,Y>::type` is the type of `true?std::declval<X>():std::declval<Y>()`, it appears that `common_type<int&, int&>::type` is not `int&` but rather `int`.  Strange.

Comment: I think the base case should have a single argument, this also removes the need to separate `T2&& v0` from the parameter pack.  See http://ideone.com/5J6BBw

Comment: Oh better yet, lose the `std::common_type` entirely.  See http://ideone.com/OcQZ06

Comment: @Yakk I think it is so because `common_type<int&, float&>::type` can not be `float&`.

Comment: @benvoigt that is C++1y.  And, in theory, `common_type` does things `?` cannot do.  More fixes inc.

Comment: Now uses `if`.  Passing in `std::chrono` types will show a difference, as `?` does not know `common_type` specializations.

Comment: @constructor and in that case it should return `float` or `double`.  Need to standard delve, then fix cpprefernce docks, as they are in error, or ideone compiler is, or both.

Comment: @Yakk As I can see the key is in the line `typedef decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>()) type;` in the implementation of `std::common_type` for two arguments. To be exact the cause is in the behavior of `?` operator.

Comment: @Constructor as demonstrated [here](https://ideone.com/FvvmvC), `common_type<int&, int&>::type` is not the same as `decltype( true?std::declval<int&>():std::declval<int&>())` (replacing `y_t x` with `x_t x` makes it fail to compile).  Maybe different version of `common_type`?

Comment: @Constructor [bah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975812/should-stdcommon-type-use-stddecay), a `decay` was added, so there is no way to make a high quality `min` that works like chained `?` and supports `common_type` specializations.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I have already [noticed](http://ideone.com/rOPEa2) that they are not the same. I think it is very strange.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, it is an interesting and sad reference. But what do you mean by "a high quality `min`" ? A possibility to assign a value to a result of `min` call? I think it is not so important. But adding `std::decay_t` to `std::common_type` is rather unexpected and unpleasant change.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou No, it is not the cause. See the [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21976059/3043539) which is given by Yakk.

Comment: Stepanov argues that `min(a, b)` should return `a` iff `a <= b`, that is, `b < a ? b : a`. Has to do with "natural order" and is related to stability. Somewhere in this series: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIHAEYyoTUc

Comment: @dyp good point, one more edit toward community wikification!  I should write a better `common_type` and use it as well, because `min(a,b)=c` is just too much fun to write. (sadly, rarity of `operator=(...)&&=delete` probably makes it dangerous)

Comment: You have a typo, the first branch of the `if` ends with a colon instead of semicolon.

Comment: The semantic of `vmin` should be the same for the 1 argument version and for more arguments. But if you pass one lvalue `a` to `vmin` then the expression `vmin(a)` is an lvalue while in all other cases it is a prvalue. Solution: change the return type to `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type`.

Comment: @MWid actually, I intend to change it to being an lvalue reference for many types, if the types are all lvalue reference and match.  The goal is to match the semantics of `?` extended with `common_type` support, and to eliminate needless copies.  Plus add support for user-defined binary comparators/pickers.

Comment: @Blastfurnace fixed your typo when I added another implementation.

Comment: I think you can still break `my_common_type` with malicious specializations of `common_type<T0, T0>::type != T0`; also `struct X { operator int&(); }; my_common_type<X, int&>::type` will not return an lvalue ref as far as I can see. I'm not sure if I didn't want an rvalue ref for `x = min(func1(), func2())`. IIRC you said `min(func1(), func2()) = x;` is dangerous if the first one is an rvalue? Isn't that the problem of the user? (`std::common_type` is broken)

Comment: @dyp Such a specialization would ignore the malicious specialization of `std::common_type`, so not sure if that is a 'break'.  Your `X` is interesting, hmm. Returning rvalue refs is usually wrong outside of casts (like `move` or `forward`), as reference lifetime extension relies on returning values in that case. The danger is with `common_type_t<A,C>=C` if `struct A {}; struct C{ C(C const&)=default; C(A const&):x(0); int x=2; bool operator<(C const& o)const{return x<o.x;};};A a;C x,y; my_min::min( x,y,a ) = C{}; my_min::min( x,y )=C{};`: one is an assignment that is discarded, the other not.

Comment: @dyp aha: check if `U` and `T` can be converted to `std_type&`?  Maybe also that they are lvalues?  That might catch thise corner cases: spot any flaws?

Comment: I think we cannot know whether we're using a specialization of `common_type` or the general case. Some class `derived` can be converted to `base&`, but a specialization might want to create a new object: `common_type<base&, derived&>::type == base`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Wouldn't using an `auto&&` return type and let the compiler perfectly forward the arguments solve most problems mentioned here? I've seen the approached mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73290633/4224575) used w/o problems so far. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @LorahAttkins No, `auto&&` never causes temporary lifetime extension in return values.

Comment: @LorahAttkins Or to be more explicit, sometimes min of non-uniform types requires conversion, which requires storage.  `auto&&` does not permit storage.  So you must have a dangling return value in that case (or something equally ugly, like global/thread local storage for it).

Answer (score 18):

I appreciate the thought Yakk put into return types so I wouldn't have to, but it gets a lot simpler:

```
template<typename T>
T&& vmin(T&& val)
{
    return std::forward<T>(val);
}

template<typename T0, typename T1, typename... Ts>
auto vmin(T0&& val1, T1&& val2, Ts&&... vs)
{
    return (val1 < val2) ?
      vmin(val1, std::forward<Ts>(vs)...) :
      vmin(val2, std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
}
```

Return type deduction is pretty awesome (may require C++14).

Comment: *"may require C++14"* It *does* require C++1y. I wonder if `decltype(auto)` might be a better choice here. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815138/implementing-variadic-min-max-functions#comment36643409_23816018

Comment: Pass it two `std::chrono` types that differ: `common_type` is smarter than `?`

Comment: @Yakk: But which result is "better"?  Is it necessary that `vmin` work on types for which `?:` does not?

Comment: @BenVoigt: A question, what is the advantageous of `&&` in this case rather than `const &` while the `min` isn't copying or modifying the inputs? Isn't it better to pass the inputs by `const &` (which doesn't need to perfect-forwarding) as same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497977/general-min-and-max-c/16498347#16498347)?

Comment: @MM. As I said in a comment to your question, the arguments are copied/moved. The `auto` return type deduction, like template type deduction, never deduces a reference, hence this function returns by value. (Therefore my suggestion to use `decltype(auto)`.)

Comment: @dyp: My question is about entry parameters but I think your comment is talking about returning.

Comment: @MM. Well if your parameter is a `const&`, you can only copy into the return value. If it's a universal reference, you can copy and move into the return value, depending on the argument expression (call site).

Comment: @benvoigt being able to say "the least of all of these `std::chrono` time points seems like better than the alternative, and `std::chrono` specializes `std::common_type` to tell what is the proper type for this kind of operation.  `?:` won't work.  And barring specialization, `std::common_type<A,B>::type` is `std::decay<decltype(true?a:b)>::type`, which matches your `auto`-decay.

Comment: @dyp Doesn't `decltype(auto)` results in UB if you pass in `double` and `int`, as the output is a `double&&` possibly converted from the `int`, and that `double&&` lifetime ends before the caller gets at it?  Or is there magic I'm missing?

Comment: @Yakk True. There are no prvalues with universal refs. `decltype(auto)` is useful for lvalue references, so maybe you can fix it by explicitly decaying xvalues o.O

Answer (score 14):

There is a solution in C++17 which beats all answers proposed so far:

```cpp
template <typename Head0, typename Head1, typename... Tail>
constexpr auto min(const Head0 &head0, const Head1 &head1, const Tail &... tail)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(tail) == 0) {
        return head0 < head1 ? head0 : head1;
    }
    else {
        return min(min(head0, head1), tail...);
    }
}
```

Notice how this:

- requires only one function
- you can't call this with fewer than two parameters
- it compiles optimally

Using `gcc` 10.2 with `-O3`, the accepted answer compiles to:

```
min(int, int, int):
        cmp     esi, edi
        jge     .L2
        cmp     esi, edx
        mov     eax, edx
        cmovle  eax, esi
        ret
.L2:
        cmp     edi, edx
        mov     eax, edx
        cmovle  eax, edi
        ret
```

There are more instructions and a conditional jump for whatever reason.
My solution compiles only to:

```
min(int, int, int):
        cmp     esi, edx
        mov     eax, edi
        cmovg   esi, edx
        cmp     esi, edi
        cmovle  eax, esi
        ret
```

This is identical to just calling `std::min` recursively for three parameters.
(see https://godbolt.org/z/snavK5)

Comment: You should `std::forward<Tail>(tail)...`.

Comment: @darkdragon thanks for the suggestion. Using `&&` without forwarding was wrong, but we also cannot use `std::forward` for `Head0` and `Head1` because they're used twice, and if the less-than operator is overloaded with rvalue-qualification, returning a value may be use-after-move. This is why I've opted for using `const&` everywhere instead.

Answer (score 5):

4) Here is one possible way to implement a `constexpr` version of this function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
constexpr typename std::common_type<Arg1, Arg2>::type vmin(Arg1&& arg1, Arg2&& arg2)
{
    return arg1 < arg2 ? std::forward<Arg1>(arg1) : std::forward<Arg2>(arg2);
}

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
constexpr typename std::common_type<Arg, Args...>::type vmin(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    return vmin(std::forward<Arg>(arg), vmin(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << vmin(3, 2, 1, 2, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << vmin(3., 1.2, 1.3, 2., 5.2) << std::endl;
}
```

See [live example](http://ideone.com/4jbrzR).

**Edit:** As **[@Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk)** noted in comments the code `std::forward<Arg1>(arg1) < std::forward<Arg2>(arg2) ? std::forward<Arg1>(arg1) : std::forward<Arg2>(arg2)` may cause problems in some situations. `arg1 < arg2 ? std::forward<Arg1>(arg1) : std::forward<Arg2>(arg2)` is more appropriate variant in this case.

Comment: You `forward` the same argument twice along some execution paths (and not a chain).  This is a bad idea.  If an rvalue overload for `<` is destructive, you'll return nonsense.

Comment: @Yakk Oh, I think you are right. Can I steal the solution of this problem from your answer to fix my one?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference, that is why you probably get the compilation error. That is, in `vmin(3, 2, 1, 2, 5)`, the parameters are temporaries. It will work if you declare them as for example `int first=3,second=2` and so on, then invoke `vmin(first,second...)`

Answer (score 3):

With c++17and not using recursion:

```
template <typename T, T ... vals>
constexpr T get_max(std::integer_sequence<T, vals...> = std::integer_sequence<T, vals...>())
{
     T arr[sizeof...(vals)]{vals...},
         max = 0;
     for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof...(vals); ++i)
            max = arr[i] > max ? max = arr[i] : max;
     return max;
}
```

Function can be called by providing either template parameters or integer sequence as argument

```
get_max<int, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, -42>();

using seq = std::integer_sequence<int, ...>;
get_max(seq());
```

Comment: How I can calculate max type in case I have only type parameters, and want type is also be a result. Try this way but seems with only type sequence it is not working: template <typename ...Ts>
struct max {
 using seq = std::integer_sequence<Ts...>;
 using type = decltype( get_max( seq() ) );
};

Comment: @SergeyInozemcev `using seq = std::integer_sequence<Ts...>` makes no sence and won't compile in the first: you are trying to instantiate a template specialization with variadic template arguments `Ts...`. But `std::integer_sequense` only accepts non-template parameters. Looking at your code I guess you don' need to use `decltype` but `std::common_type` if you have an array of types.

Answer (score 2):

### C++20 version

The solution presented by @Yakk-AdamNevraumont is good, it covers very well aspects of lvalue and rvalue, not allowing to return a reference to a temporary, and yet returning lvalue reference if you can.

But the solution can now be modernized for C++20 and [become much more concise and elegant](https://godbolt.org/z/91c13x9Yz):

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct common_return {
    using type = std::common_reference_t<Ts...>;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    requires std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T> &&
            (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<Ts> && ...)
            && ( std::same_as<T, Ts> && ... )
struct common_return<T, Ts...> {
    using type = std::common_reference_t<T, Ts...>&;
};

template<typename... Ts>
using common_return_t = typename common_return<Ts...>::type;

namespace my_min {
    template<typename T>
    T min(T&& t) {
        return std::forward<T>(t);
    }

    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
    common_return_t<T1, T2, Ts...> min(T1&& t1, T2&& t2, Ts&&... ts) {
        if(t2 > t1) {
            return min(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
        }
        return min(std::forward<T2>(t2), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution with a lambda and set

```cpp
auto max = [](auto&& e1, auto&& e2, auto&&... args)
{
    return *std::set<typename std::decay_t<decltype(e1)>>{e1,e2,args...}.rbegin();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With **C++11**, this solution should be fine ( with using std::max / std::min) :

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
T Max(T arg)
{
return arg;
}
template<typename T, typename Ts>
T Max(T arg, Ts... args)
{
return std::max(arg, Max(args...));
}
```

The performance is not so different from above solutions.

(It is checked via Microsoft VS 2019 / no optimization, using chrono library)

- Calling the function with single element is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to leverage an `auto&&` return type and perfectly forward your results:

```cpp
template <class T, class... Ts>
auto&& Min(T&& arg1, Ts&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts))
    {
        auto &&rmin = Min(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        return arg1 < rmin ? std::forward<T>(arg1) : rmin;
    }
    else
    {
        return std::forward<T>(arg1);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89242c3f0efeaffc)