# Requested Survey for VC++ regarding insert and emplace

Tags: visual-c++, c++11

I am doing a survey of how many special member functions get executed during the following member functions of `vector`:

```
insert
emplace
push_back
emplace_back
```

under various run time conditions.  My intent is to publish a paper that will compare these member functions with each other, and on each of the c++11 implementations of the std::lib: libstdc++, libc++, and vc++, and offer advice on when it is best to use each member function (when more than one choice is possible).  I have data on libc++ and libstdc++-4.8, but I am lacking data on vc++.

I am looking for answers on vc++ which include the vc++ version number (2010, 2012, 2013).  My intent is to give advice on the when each of these members should be preferred, and tempered by real-world experience.  I will up-vote the first response for each vc++ version.  My intent is not to bash any particular platform.  However should my results encourage any existing platform to improve in the future, then that's gravy.

The test I would like to see the results of is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class X
{
    int i_;
    int* p_;

public:
    struct special
    {
        unsigned c;
        unsigned dt;
        unsigned cc;
        unsigned ca;
        unsigned mc;
        unsigned ma;
    };
    static special sp;

    X(int i, int* p)
        : i_(i)
        , p_(p)
    {
//         std::cout << "X(int i, int* p)\n";
        sp.c++;
    }

    ~X()
    {
//         std::cout << "~X()\n";
        sp.dt++;
    }

    X(const X& x)
        : i_(x.i_)
        , p_(x.p_)
    {
//         std::cout << "X(const X& x)\n";
        sp.cc++;
    }

    X& operator=(const X& x)
    {

        i_ = x.i_;
        p_ = x.p_;
//         std::cout << "X& operator=(const X& x)\n";
        sp.ca++;
        return *this;
    }

    X(X&& x) noexcept
        : i_(x.i_)
        , p_(x.p_)
    {
//         std::cout << "X(X&& x)\n";
        sp.mc++;
    }

    X& operator=(X&& x) noexcept
    {

        i_ = x.i_;
        p_ = x.p_;
//         std::cout << "X& operator=(X&& x)\n";
        sp.ma++;
        return *this;
    }

};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, X::special const& sp)
{
    os << sp.c << '\n';
    os << sp.dt << '\n';
    os << sp.cc << '\n';
    os << sp.ca << '\n';
    os << sp.mc << '\n';
    os << sp.ma << '\n';
    return os;
}

X::special X::sp{};

int
main()
{
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--insert lvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.insert(v.begin(), x);
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--emplace lvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace(v.begin(), x);
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--insert xvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.insert(v.begin(), std::move(x));
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--emplace xvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace(v.begin(), std::move(x));
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        std::cout << "--insert rvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.insert(v.begin(), X{0,0});
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        std::cout << "--emplace rvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace(v.begin(), X{0,0});
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--insert lvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.insert(v.begin(), x);
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--emplace lvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace(v.begin(), x);
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--insert xvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.insert(v.begin(), std::move(x));
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--emplace xvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace(v.begin(), std::move(x));
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        std::cout << "--insert rvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.insert(v.begin(), X{0,0});
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        std::cout << "--emplace rvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace(v.begin(), X{0,0});
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }

    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--push_back lvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.push_back(x);
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--emplace_back lvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace_back(x);
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--push_back xvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.push_back(std::move(x));
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--emplace_back xvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace_back(std::move(x));
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        std::cout << "--push_back rvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.push_back(X{0,0});
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(4);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        std::cout << "--emplace_back rvalue no reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace_back(X{0,0});
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--push_back lvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.push_back(x);
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--emplace_back lvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace_back(x);
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--push_back xvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.push_back(std::move(x));
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        X x{0,0};
        std::cout << "--emplace_back xvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace_back(std::move(x));
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        std::cout << "--push_back rvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.push_back(X{0,0});
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
    {
        std::vector<X> v;
        v.reserve(3);
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        v.push_back(X(0,0));
        std::cout << "--emplace_back rvalue reallocation--\n";
        X::sp = {};
        v.emplace_back(X{0,0});
        std::cout << X::sp;
        std::cout << "----\n";
    }
}
```

For example, here is the output of this test on gcc-4.8: https://ideone.com/imAMnU

If someone discovers that the results are different on a gcc version after 4.8 and wants to offer those results, that would also be appreciated (and upvoted).  In the event that I am unable to distinguish which equivalent responses came first, I am happy to upvote all of them.  However at this time I am uncertain how I will choose a correct answer to this survey.

Contributors of data will surely be gratefully acknowledged in anything I might publish.  I am also happy to post a link in this question to any conclusions that might be drawn from this data in the future.

In summary, I realize that this style of question is not the norm for SO.  However it is asked in the spirit of furthering public knowledge in the C++ community, and with as much transparency as I can manage.  If people want to close this question for whatever reasons, I accept that, but personally do not feel that is in the best interest of the C++ community.

**Update**

Here is the paper I spoke of that this survey made possible:

> [`insert` vs `emplace`](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/HowardHinnant/papers/blob/master/insert_vs_emplace.html)

Comment: "how many special member functions get executed during the following member functions of vector" - isn't that a Schrodingers Cat type of question? The measurement code is quite unusual in those special member functions, which otherwise could be implemented as memcpy's.

Comment: I did indeed vote to close, simply because this is not a question. I don't see what prevents you from spinning up some VMs, downloading some Express editions, and running the code for yourself. And I'm definitely not feeling any community-generic advantage in this exceedingly specialist implementation-specific knowledge. Not to mention the possible effects of stuff like varying optimization flags, using clang-cl instead of cl, that kind of thing. This is a Mechanical Turk job, not a question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a survey.

Comment: It is my opinion that this question is salvageable. As an example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910161/does-type-order-in-stdtuple-arguments-have-any-effects)’s an example of a question which answer(s) pointedly refer to several existing implementations.

Comment: I have aggressively edited down the OP to reduce it to what I think is a more typical SO format. In particular, I suggest you move the motivation / background to e.g. a blog post linking to this question (perhaps linking back to that post from here). Understandably I may have removed too much from my edit, so anyone should feel free to improve on that.

Comment: @LucDanton: That question does not simply ask for the output of some code on the implementations.

Comment: My sincere thanks to those who provided answers (which I've up voted).  And my apologies for the down votes you unnecessarily suffered from self-righteous pin heads.

Comment: I would also like to thank Luc Danton for trying to salvage this question by editing it.  I reverted your edits only because the question wasn't salvageable, and I preferred my rationale for asking it.  But as far as I'm concerned, the question was a success.  I gathered the data I requested.  Thanks again to those who provided that data.  I am learning...

Comment: @HowardHinnant : Nice paper, thanks for posting it! BTW, on VS2013 I get 0 move-assignments for `insert lvalue reallocation`, not 6.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks ildjarn!  I've updated the paper with your correction.  That was strictly my mistake in copying the data.

Comment: nice experiment! so why are the non-libc++ (in particular VS2013) implementations doing so many extra operations? are they missing some expression simplications, are they doing unnecessary checks?

Comment: another point: for prvalues, why you are doing `v.emplace(v.begin(), X{0,0})` instead of `v.emplace(v.begin(), 0, 0)`? I though the point of emplace was to let it sort out the constructor?

Comment: @TemplateRex: I can't answer your first question. On your second question, the intent of the paper is to compare `insert` and `emplace` for the case where either can be used (i.e. to insert an `x`). I have since concluded (with Jonathan Wakely's help) that an implementation can always make `insert` and `emplace` behave identical to one another for this restricted use case (and implementations -hint gcc- may do so in the future). Comparing `insert(i, x)` to `emplace(i, {0,0})` will be another interesting experiment. I might put that experiment in this paper in the future.

Comment: tnx, would be an interesting experiment. I have sometimes code like `x = init(a,b); if (pred(x)) insert(i, x));` which can be done cheaper with `if (pred(a, b)) emplace(i, {a, b});` because it delays full construction of an object and only requires passing some arguments.

Comment: @TemplateRex:  Nice example, thanks!

Comment: Hi Howard, [here](https://gist.github.com/dodheim/8ad418951b172dd4fe55ec4222f8e6bd) is the output for VC++ 2017 RC (in case you're keeping this up to date). :-]

Answer (score 6):

VS2012 Code compiled with Release mode.

**Command**

cl /O2 /EHsc /W4 Console_12.cpp

**Output**

```
--insert lvalue no reallocation--    
4        
4        
1        
3        
4  
0           
----    
--emplace lvalue no reallocation--    
8    
15    
2    
3    
10    
6    
----    
--insert xvalue no reallocation--    
12    
26    
2    
3    
17    
12    
----    
--emplace xvalue no reallocation--    
16    
37    
2    
3    
24    
18    
----    
--insert rvalue no reallocation--    
20    
49    
2    
3    
31    
24    
----    
--emplace rvalue no reallocation--    
24    
60    
2    
3    
38    
30    
----    
--insert lvalue reallocation--    
28    
70    
3    
3    
44    
30    
----    
--emplace lvalue reallocation--    
32    
84    
4    
3    
53    
36    
----    
--insert xvalue reallocation--    
36    
98    
4    
3    
63    
42    
----    
--emplace xvalue reallocation--    
40    
112    
4    
3    
73    
48    
----    
--insert rvalue reallocation--    
44    
127    
4    
3    
83    
54    
----    
--emplace rvalue reallocation--    
48    
141    
4    
3    
93    
60    
----    
--push_back lvalue no reallocation--    
52    
148    
5    
3    
96    
60    
----    
--emplace_back lvalue no reallocation--    
56    
156    
6    
3    
99    
60    
----    
--push_back xvalue no reallocation--    
60    
164    
6    
3    
103    
60    
----    
--emplace_back xvalue no reallocation--    
64    
172    
6    
3    
107    
60    
----    
--push_back rvalue no reallocation--    
68    
181    
6    
3    
111    
60    
----    
--emplace_back rvalue no reallocation--    
72    
189    
6    
3    
115    
60    
----    
--push_back lvalue reallocation--    
76    
199    
7    
3    
121    
60    
----    
--emplace_back lvalue reallocation--    
80    
210    
8    
3    
127    
60    
----    
--push_back xvalue reallocation--    
84    
221    
8    
3    
134    
60    
----    
--emplace_back xvalue reallocation--    
88    
232    
8    
3    
141    
60    
----    
--push_back rvalue reallocation--    
92    
244    
8    
3    
148    
60    
----    
--emplace_back rvalue reallocation--    
96    
255    
8    
3    
155    
60    
----
```

Answer (score 5):

## VS2013

Added `#define noexcept` which I believe will have been done in the VS2010 and 2012 cases as well.

Release results:

```
/GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\Howard.pch" 

--insert lvalue no reallocation--
0
1
1
3
1
0
----
--emplace lvalue no reallocation--
0
3
1
0
3
6
----
--insert xvalue no reallocation--
0
3
0
0
4
6
----
--emplace xvalue no reallocation--
0
3
0
0
4
6
----
--insert rvalue no reallocation--
1
4
0
0
4
6
----
--emplace rvalue no reallocation--
1
4
0
0
4
6
----
--insert lvalue reallocation--
0
3
1
0
3
0
----
--emplace lvalue reallocation--
0
6
1
0
6
6
----
--insert xvalue reallocation--
0
6
0
0
7
6
----
--emplace xvalue reallocation--
0
6
0
0
7
6
----
--insert rvalue reallocation--
1
7
0
0
7
6
----
--emplace rvalue reallocation--
1
7
0
0
7
6
----
--push_back lvalue no reallocation
0
0
1
0
0
0
----
--emplace_back lvalue no reallocat
0
0
1
0
0
0
----
--push_back xvalue no reallocation
0
0
0
0
1
0
----
--emplace_back xvalue no reallocat
0
0
0
0
1
0
----
--push_back rvalue no reallocation
1
1
0
0
1
0
----
--emplace_back rvalue no reallocat
1
1
0
0
1
0
----
--push_back lvalue reallocation--
0
3
1
0
3
0
----
--emplace_back lvalue reallocation
0
3
1
0
3
0
----
--push_back xvalue reallocation--
0
3
0
0
4
0
----
--emplace_back xvalue reallocation
0
3
0
0
4
0
----
--push_back rvalue reallocation--
1
4
0
0
4
0
----
--emplace_back rvalue reallocation
1
4
0
0
4
0
----
```

Debug results:

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" 

--insert lvalue no reallocation--
0
1
1
3
1
0
----
--emplace lvalue no reallocation-
0
3
1
0
3
6
----
--insert xvalue no reallocation--
0
3
0
0
4
6
----
--emplace xvalue no reallocation-
0
3
0
0
4
6
----
--insert rvalue no reallocation--
1
4
0
0
4
6
----
--emplace rvalue no reallocation-
1
4
0
0
4
6
----
--insert lvalue reallocation--
0
3
1
0
3
0
----
--emplace lvalue reallocation--
0
6
1
0
6
6
----
--insert xvalue reallocation--
0
6
0
0
7
6
----
--emplace xvalue reallocation--
0
6
0
0
7
6
----
--insert rvalue reallocation--
1
7
0
0
7
6
----
--emplace rvalue reallocation--
1
7
0
0
7
6
----
--push_back lvalue no reallocatio
0
0
1
0
0
0
----
--emplace_back lvalue no realloca
0
0
1
0
0
0
----
--push_back xvalue no reallocatio
0
0
0
0
1
0
----
--emplace_back xvalue no realloca
0
0
0
0
1
0
----
--push_back rvalue no reallocatio
1
1
0
0
1
0
----
--emplace_back rvalue no realloca
1
1
0
0
1
0
----
--push_back lvalue reallocation--
0
3
1
0
3
0
----
--emplace_back lvalue reallocatio
0
3
1
0
3
0
----
--push_back xvalue reallocation--
0
3
0
0
4
0
----
--emplace_back xvalue reallocatio
0
3
0
0
4
0
----
--push_back rvalue reallocation--
1
4
0
0
4
0
----
--emplace_back rvalue reallocatio
1
4
0
0
4
0
----
```

Comment: Wouldn't changing `noexcept` to `throw()` be more in the spirit of things?

Answer (score 4):

VS2010 Code Compiled with Release Mode.

**Command**

cl /O2 /EHsc /W4 EmplaceTest.cpp

**Output**

```
--insert lvalue no reallocation--
4
6
1
0
6
6
----
--emplace lvalue no reallocation--
8
17
2
0
12
12
----
--insert xvalue no reallocation--
12
28
2
0
19
18
----
--emplace xvalue no reallocation--
16
39
2
0
26
24
----
--insert rvalue no reallocation--
20
51
2
0
33
30
----
--emplace rvalue no reallocation--
24
62
2
0
40
36
----
--insert lvalue reallocation--
28
75
3
0
49
42
----
--emplace lvalue reallocation--
32
89
4
0
58
48
----
--insert xvalue reallocation--
36
103
4
0
68
54
----
--emplace xvalue reallocation--
40
117
4
0
78
60
----
--insert rvalue reallocation--
44
132
4
0
88
66
----
--emplace rvalue reallocation--
48
146
4
0
98
72
----
--push_back lvalue no reallocation--
52
153
5
0
101
72
----
--emplace_back lvalue no reallocation--
56
161
6
0
104
72
----
--push_back xvalue no reallocation--
60
169
6
0
108
72
----
--emplace_back xvalue no reallocation--
64
177
6
0
112
72
----
--push_back rvalue no reallocation--
68
186
6
0
116
72
----
--emplace_back rvalue no reallocation--
72
194
6
0
120
72
----
--push_back lvalue reallocation--
76
204
7
0
126
72
----
--emplace_back lvalue reallocation--
80
215
8
0
132
72
----
--push_back xvalue reallocation--
84
226
8
0
139
72
----
--emplace_back xvalue reallocation--
88
237
8
0
146
72
----
--push_back rvalue reallocation--
92
249
8
0
153
72
----
--emplace_back rvalue reallocation--
96
260
8
0
160
72
----
```