# How to find the largest possible sizeof child class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Given a class, I would like to find the largest `sizeof()` all child classes of it in compile-time. In this case, you will need to properly define the value of `B::BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE`, preferably in the class itself.

It is possible to do so in a separate chunk of code with the usage of `std::max()` as shown in the last line, but it's some what duplicate code and unelegant, as I will have to continuously modify that line as more classes inherit from `B`.

I would like a nice scalable solution instead.

```
struct B 
{
    static const int BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE;
};

struct D1 : public B
{
    int i;
};

struct D2 : public B
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
};

struct D3 : public B
{
    std::string s;
};

const int B::BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE = std::max(sizeof(D1), std::max(sizeof(D2), sizeof(D3)));
```

The value of `BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE` should be "32", due to `std::string`.

Any elegant solutions for this?
The sexier the templates, the better.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible to do so in a separate chunk of code with the usage of std::max as shown in the last line, but it's some what duplicate code and unelegant, as I will have to continuously modify that line as more classes inherit from B.
>
> I would like a nice scalable solution instead.

Unfortunately, I don't know a way to automatically know all derived types (I don't think it's possible) so I fear that you needs "to continuously modify that line as more classes inherit form `B`".

In LogicStuff's answer you see an elegant way to simplify that line and I also remember that exist the `std::max()` version that receive a `std::initializer_list` (`constexpr` starting from C++14) so you can also write (but the `biggest_size_v` way is better, IMHO)

```
const int B::BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE
   = std::max({sizeof(D1), sizeof(D2), sizeof(D3)});
```

avoiding the multiple `std::max()` calls.

A little off topic, I suppose, but I propose you a semi-automatic way to check, compile-time, that `B::BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE` is bigger (or equal) to the `sizeof()` of all derived types (all instantiated derived type, at least).

If you modify `B` adding a constructor with a `static_assert()` in it (or SFINAE enabled, if you prefer)

```
struct B 
 {
   static const int BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE;

   template <std::size_t DerSize>
   B (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, DerSize>)
    { static_assert( DerSize <= BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE, "!" ); }
 };
```

and add a template `C` struct that inherit from `B`

```
template <typename Der>
struct C : public B
 {
   C() : B{std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof(Der)>{}}
    { }
 };
```

if you modify your `Dx` classes to inheriting `B` passing through `C<Dx>` (so using CRTP)

```
struct D1 : public C<D1>
 { int i; };

struct D2 : public C<D2>
 { std::vector<int> vec; };

struct D3 : public C<D3>
 { std::string s; };
```

you auto-magically enable the compile-time check inside `B` constructor.

So if you add, by example, the following `D4` class

```
struct D4 : public C<D4>
 { int a[42]; };
```

and forget to modify the `BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE` initialization adding `sizeof(D4)` in the list, declaring a `D4` object you get a compilation error

```
D4 d4; // compilation error
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct B 
 {
   static const int BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE;

   template <std::size_t DerSize>
   B (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, DerSize>)
    { static_assert( DerSize <= BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE, "!" ); }
 };

template <typename Der>
struct C : public B
 {
   C() : B{std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof(Der)>{}}
    { }
 };

struct D1 : public C<D1>
 { int i; };

struct D2 : public C<D2>
 { std::vector<int> vec; };

struct D3 : public C<D3>
 { std::string s; };

struct D4 : public C<D4>
 { int a[42]; };

const int B::BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE
   = std::max({sizeof(D1), sizeof(D2), sizeof(D3)}); // <-- sizeof(D4) forgotten !!!

int main ()
 {
   D1 d1;
   D2 d2;
   D3 d3;
   // D4 d4;  compilation error
 }
```

Comment: While it is unfortunate that I will have to write somewhere along the lines of

```C++
std::max({sizeof(Ts)...})
```

Your static assert solution in the ctor is indeed sexy!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take for example [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), it knows its size from the template arguments. Your best shot is also to use a variadic template. First, you implement [the variadic `max` function template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815138/implementing-variadic-min-max-functions), then you use it:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr bool biggest_size_v = max(sizeof(Ts)...);
```

If you're asking to automatically get a list of all derived classes at compile-time. You can't. You still have to list them:

```
const int B::BIGGEST_TYPE_SIZE = biggest_size_v<D1, D2, D3>;
```

Comment: Or maybe simply `std::max({sizeof(Ts)...})`?