# How to avoid an invalid overload from the std library?

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, overload-resolution

In my C++14 project I'm using

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::max;            // for max(a,b)
```

but I also want to provide a `max()` function taking any number of arguments (of equal type). To this end, I added

```
template<typename T, typename...A>
constexpr inline T const& max(T const&x, T const&y, A...&&z)
{
    return max(max(x,y), std::forward<A>(z)...);
}
```

but upon a call like

```
double x,y,z;
...
auto m = max(x,y,z);
```

the compiler tries to instead of my overload use

```
namespace std {
template< class T, class Compare >
constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp );
}
```

from `algorithm`. How can I avoid that (but still provide the intended functionality)?

(Note that there is a [question about variadic min/max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815138/implementing-variadic-min-max-functions), but it doesn't address the issue I have by simply changing the name to `vmin`/`vmax`.)

Comment: There is an overload of `std::max` that takes an initializer list. Perhaps that would work for you instead? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Comment: Don't do `using std::max` -- use explicit namespace resolution everywhere.

Comment: @RetiredNinja this is not a solution, as it does not *provide the intended functionality*. Same applies to wochran's comment.

Comment: It should be noted that the reason that  the std::max overload is being called is because double can implicitly be converted to bool, which makes the overload take higher precedence than unpacking the parameter pack and continuing the expansion

Comment: @mkamerath why bool?

Comment: Why not put your `max` in its own namespace?

Comment: @Den-Jason how would that help?

Comment: @Walter never mind, I tested the answer candidate and it works.  I have provided a demonstration for anyone who may be interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved by only overloading the function for 3 or more arguments like:

```
template<typename T, typename...A>
constexpr inline T const& max(T const&x, T const&y, T const&z, A&&...w)
{
    return max(max(x,y), z, std::forward<A>(w)...);
}
```

Comment: To clarify: does this work because this template's specializations (those with `A = []`) are considered to be more specific than the ones for the one in the standard library and is therefore chosen over that one when possible?

Comment: @HTNW I think so. And I'm still reading the standard [\[over.match.best\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best).

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

Either stop `using std::max` and qualify your namespaces instead, or name your function something else.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can simply use [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) which takes an initializer list.

An example call would be:

```
auto maxNum = std::max({a, b, c});
```

Comment: sorry, but this does not meet the criterion stated (*provide the intended functionality*)

Comment: @Walter _"this does not meet the criterion stated"_ In what way?

Comment: according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max it states that `T must meet the requirements of CopyConstructible in order to use overloads (3,4). ` and I guess that is the reason for not using the initialiser list overload...... and hence Walter's comment about non-copyable objects ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings in two ways: (1) I have to change `max(a,b,c)` everywhere in my project -- at the moment this is implemented via an overload, not a variadic template. (2) it will fail for non-copy-constructible objects and will create undesired copies of large objects.

Comment: @Walter Neither of those criteria were stated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest yao99's answer should be the accepted one.  For sake of curiosity, here I present you with a solution that provides an adaptor through your own namespace.  This only ever uses the binary parameter overload of `std::max` so there is no possibility of the initialiser list overload becoming invoked.  The client code can still use `max` as indicated:

The adaptor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

namespace variadicMax
{
    // the variadic "max" recurses and reduces to a binary parameter version that we must implement
    template<typename T>
    constexpr inline T const& max(T const&x, T const&y)
    {
        return (std::max(x, y));
    }

    // the variadic overload recurses itself, removing two parameters (and adding one) each time.
    // Eventually it reduces to (x,y) which is handled by the other overload.
    template<typename T, typename...Args>
    constexpr inline T const& max(T const&x, T const&y, Args&&...z)
    {
        return (max (std::max(x, y), std::forward<Args>(z)...));
    }
};
```

The client:

```
// this is the only change needed in clients:
using variadicMax::max;

int main()
{
    double x, y, z, w, v;

    x = 1;  y = 2;  z = 3;  w = 4;  v = 5;
    auto m5 = max(x, y, z, w, v);  std::cout << m5 << std::endl;
    auto m5A = max(x, y, z, 4.0, v);  std::cout << m5A << std::endl;

    x = 1;  y = 2;  z = 3;
    auto m = max(x, y, z);  std::cout << m << std::endl;

    x = 2;  y = 3;  z = 1;
    auto m2 = max(x, y, z);  std::cout << m2 << std::endl;

    x = 3;  y = 2;  z = 1;
    auto m3 = max(x, y, z);  std::cout << m3 << std::endl;

    x = 3;  y = 2;
    auto m4 = max(x, y);  std::cout << m4 << std::endl;

    x = 3;  y = 2;
    auto m6 = max(3, 2);  std::cout << m6 << std::endl;

    x = 3;  y = 2;
    auto m7 = max(x, 2.0);  std::cout << m7 << std::endl;

    etc...
```