# Recursive trailing return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trailing return type using decltype with a variadic template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744400/trailing-return-type-using-decltype-with-a-variadic-template-function)

I want to make a function that sums up several values. If I don't use a trailing return type then `count()` uses the type of the first argument as it's return type. However, when using a trailing return type I am not able to get the code to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
inline T sum(T a) {
  return a;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
inline auto sum(T a, Args... b) -> decltype(a + sum(b...)) {
  return (a + sum(b...));
}

int main() {
  std::cout << sum(1, 2.5f, 3, 4);
  return 0;
}
```

The error (GCC) is:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘sum(int, float, int, int)’
main.cpp:16:30: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:5:10: note: template<class T> T sum(T)
main.cpp:10:13: note: template<class T, class ... Args> decltype ((a + sum(sum::b ...))) sum(T, Args ...)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Isn't `count` supposed to be `sum`?

Comment: Where's int main() with the problematic line 16?
http://sscce.org/

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/v8nJK

Comment: @jpalecek: It works with 2 parameters, but not with 3 or more: http://ideone.com/CYCZE

Comment: @JakubWieczorek It does seem to be an exact duplicate. I'll flag for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but I got it working using a template struct:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
struct sum_helper;

template<typename T>
struct sum_helper<T> {
  typedef T sum_type;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct sum_helper<T, Args...> {
  typedef decltype(*(T*)0 + *(typename sum_helper<Args...>::sum_type*)0) sum_type;
};

template<typename T>
inline T sum(T a) {
  return a;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
inline typename sum_helper<T, Args...>::sum_type sum(T a, Args... b) {
  return a + sum(b...);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << sum(1, 2, 3) << " "
        << sum(1, 1.1, 1.11) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/7wYXf