# What's wrong (if anything) with this implementation of a C++11 variadic sum function?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trailing return type using decltype with a variadic template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744400/trailing-return-type-using-decltype-with-a-variadic-template-function)

I'm getting this compiler error:

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x -I. -O3 -Wall sum.cpp
sum.cpp:7:41: sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand ‘Remaining ...’ into a fixed-length argument list
sum.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
sum.cpp:29:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘sum(int, int, int)’
sum.cpp:29:23: note: candidate is:
sum.cpp:20:6: note: template<class FirstArg, class ... RemainingArgs> decltype (Sum<FirstArg, RemainingArgs ...>::sum(first, sum::args ...)) sum(const FirstArg&, const RemainingArgs& ...)
```

for this *sum.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename First, typename... Remaining>
struct Sum {
   static auto sum(const First &arg, const Remaining &... args)
      -> decltype(arg + Sum<Remaining...>::sum(args...))
   {
      return arg + sum(args...);
   }
};

template <typename First>
struct Sum<First>
{
   static First sum(const First &arg) { return arg; }
};

template <typename FirstArg, typename... RemainingArgs>
auto sum(const FirstArg &first, const RemainingArgs &... args)
   -> decltype(Sum<FirstArg, RemainingArgs...>::sum(first, args...))
{
   return Sum<FirstArg, RemainingArgs...>::sum(first, args...);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   using ::std::cout;
   cout << sum(1, 2, 3) << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

I've tried multiple means of declaring this function. Is this just a problem with gcc 4.6.1?

---

**Edit:** Here is what I finally went with because I don't really trust the `::std::common_type` template. It still has a problem though, it will bind `+` from right  to left instead of from left to right. This may cause problems with non-commutative `+` operators. That's not very hard to fix though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace {
template<class T> typename ::std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type val();

template<class T> struct id{typedef T type;};

template<class T, class... P> struct sum_type;
template<class T> struct sum_type<T> : id< T > {};
template<class T, class U, class... P> struct sum_type<T,U,P...>
: sum_type< decltype( val<const T&>() + val<const U&>() ), P... > {};
}

template <typename T>
T sum(const T &&arg)
{
   return ::std::forward<const T>(arg);
}

template <typename FirstArg, typename SecondArg, typename... RemainingArgs>
auto sum(const FirstArg &&first, const SecondArg &&second,
         const RemainingArgs &&... args)
   -> typename sum_type<FirstArg, SecondArg, RemainingArgs...>::type
{
   using ::std::forward;

   return forward<const FirstArg>(first) + \
      sum(forward<const SecondArg>(second),
          forward<const RemainingArgs>(args)...);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   using ::std::cout;
   cout << sum(1, 2, 3.2) << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The short answer: you can't use `decltype` of the very function template you're defining in a trailing-return-type, because it's not declared yet.

Comment: Oops, I think I assumed this was a duplicate too soon.  Actually, I see only one minor problem here, but the idea might work.

Comment: FYI, the unimplemented functionality GCC is complaining about here has been implemented for 4.7 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first inner `sum` function that's being called recursively has the wrong signature.

For a run-time variadic function, try this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> T sum(T && x) { return std::forward<T>(x); }

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
typename std::common_type<T, Args...>::type sum(T && x, Args &&... args)
{
  return std::forward<T>(x) + sum(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


int main()
{
  return sum(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Comment: I want to sum a bunch of values that are only known at runtime even though their types are (of course) known at compile time.

Comment: @Omnifarious: OK, let me rework this. The current code doesn't work anyway. I'll be back.

Comment: This works, though using `std::common_type` feels like cheating. :-) And why the rvalue references?

Comment: @Omniarious: It's perfect forwarding.

Comment: @Omnifarious: They're not rvalue references, they're Berlusconi references: They'll be whatever you want them to be! (Observe that we're in a deducible context of a template, not in a function.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Did you just make up this 'Berlusconi reference' thing to be funny, or is it a name other people use, and if the latter, where can I find a reference to the idea?

Comment: @Omnifarious: It's a relatively new term ;-) You should look up "reference collapsing rules" to see how this type deduction works in the presence of `&&`. Herb Sutter calls it "an arcane rule", but it makes good sense.

Comment: @KerrekSB: So I can stuff `const`s in there to express that `sum` will not change its arguments.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I wouldn't bother with that. If the object you pass in at the call site is const, then `T&&` will deduce as `U const &` automatically (with `T = const U`).

Comment: @KerrekSB: +1 Your solution is very elegant and so much cleaner and generally nice than what the OP has posted - good work!

Comment: The other day I implemented a `conjunction` function that AND-ed conditions passed as variadic arguments. Now this turns up. There is a pattern here known as fold, aggregate, or reduce, depending on where you come from. It can be generalized: http://www.ideone.com/XjWWt.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: It's also available as `accumulate` in `<algorithm>` as a function version that operates on iterators. You would pick the "from-the-left" vs "from-the-right" by chosing either begin/end or rbegin/rend ranges.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The point is not to handle const reference arguments properly, the point is to let the compiler (and everybody else) know that even if a non-const reference argument is passed in that it will not be modified by the function.

Comment: There is no function, there is only a template! Important difference :-) If you have an immutable object, it *will* cause the appropriate function template instantiation. And if not, then there's nothing to worry about. (If you really, really must, you can call it with `sum(static_cast<const int &>(x), 2, 3)`, but that will gain you *nothing*.