# variadic templates sum operation left associative

Tags: c++, templates, sum, variadic-templates, decltype

The code below works for the: goal for the left associative sum operation: `sum(1,2,3,4);`

However, it won't work correctly for  `sum(1,2,3,4,5)` or `sum(1,2,3,4,5,...)`. Anything with more than 4 arguments gives the error:

> error: no matching function for call to sum(int, int, int, int, int)

=================================

```
template <typename T>
T sum(const T& v) {
return v;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2) -> decltype( v1 + v2) {
return v1 + v2;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const Ts&... rest) -> decltype( v1 + v2 +      sum(rest...) ) {
return v1 + v2 + sum(rest... );
}

int main() {
    cout << sum(1,2,3,4); //works correctly
    //cout << sum(1,2,3,4,5); //compile error

}
```

Comment: My guess is that it can't evauluate the sum using varidic template recursivly before it is decleared ones. I've no clue though how to solve it. Impossible?

Comment: I can reproduce that issue on gcc 4.7.2: http://ideone.com/6X4f2b - seems that gcc refuses to call variadic templates with auto/decltype return types recursively.

Comment: See this [link][1]. Close to identical question.  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744400/trailing-return-type-using-decltype-with-a-variadic-template-function

Comment: can be easily fixed with template class, instead of template function. I think it is right that it can't find proper function, but I am not sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems to be a bug in GCC, when working with variadic templates, auto return types and recursive reference to the same variadic template in the trailing return type.

**C++11 - only right associative**

It is solvable, through good old template meta programming:

```
//first a metafunction to calculate the result type of sum(Ts...)
template <typename...> struct SumTs;
template <typename T1> struct SumTs<T1> { typedef T1 type; };
template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct SumTs<T1, Ts...>
{
  typedef typename SumTs<Ts...>::type rhs_t;
  typedef decltype(std::declval<T1>() + std::declval<rhs_t>()) type;
};

//now the sum function
template <typename T>
T sum(const T& v) {
  return v;
}

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
auto sum(const T1& v1, const Ts&... rest) 
  -> typename SumTs<T1,Ts...>::type //instead of the decltype
{
  return v1 + sum(rest... );
}

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main() {
  cout << sum(1,2,3,4,5);    
}
```

PS: to be even more generic, the whole thing could be pimped with "universal references" and `std::forward`.

**C++17 fold expressions**

In C++17, the problem can be solved in basically one line:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto sum(T&& t, Ts&&... ts) 
{
  return (std::forward<T>(t) + ... + std::forward<Ts>(ts));
}
``
```

Comment: `std::declval<T>()` is the correct stand-in for `T()` inside of decltype.

Comment: is there have to be "auto" keyword in front of 
sum(const T1& v1, const Ts&... rest)

Comment: would it be possible to make this code work for the also Objects as arguments or only does it restrict with primitive type variables?/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665531/variadic-templated-object-multiplication

Comment: Doesn't this template produce a *right*-associative sum?  `sum(1,2,3,4,5) --> (1+(2+(3+(4+5))))` ? A left-associative sum would be this: `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`  This of course doesn't matter for `int`s but `T` could be a class with the `+` operator overloaded, and the two expressions might not be equal.

Comment: @ricovox it does. Making it left-associative would be a real hassle. These days, I would use C++17's fold expressions where we can chose the associativity.

Answer (score 2):

The function need  additional check:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T sum(T v) 
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<std::remove_reference<decltype(v)>::type>::value, 
    "type should be arithmetic");
    return v;
}
```

and it's better pass by value.

otherwise we can get strange result:

```
int main() {
std::cout << sum(1,"Hello World");


return 0;
}
```