# Template functions in namespace cause errors

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, namespaces, metaprogramming

Assume the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Link
{
    Link(T&& val) : val(std::forward<T>(val)) {}

    T val;
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Link<T>& link)
{
    out << "Link(" << link.val << ")";
    return out;
}

template<typename T>
auto MakeLink(T&& val) -> Link<T>
{
    return {std::forward<T>(val)};
}

namespace Utils {
template<typename Any>
constexpr auto RemoveLinks(const Any& any) -> const Any&
{
    return any;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto RemoveLinks(const Link<T>& link) -> decltype(RemoveLinks(link.val))
{
    return RemoveLinks(link.val);
}

} /* Utils */

int main()
{
    int k = 10;

    auto link = MakeLink(MakeLink(k));

    std::cout << link << std::endl;
    std::cout << Utils::RemoveLinks(link) << std::endl;
}
```

For some reason I can't understand, it generates the following compilation errors with `g++-4.8`:

```
/home/allan/Codes/expr.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr decltype (Utils::RemoveLinks(link.val)) Utils::RemoveLinks(const Link<T>&) [with T = int&; decltype (Utils::RemoveLinks(link.val)) = const int&]’:
/home/allan/Codes/expr.cpp:88:32:   required from ‘constexpr decltype (Utils::RemoveLinks(link.val)) Utils::RemoveLinks(const Link<T>&) [with T = Link<int&>; decltype (Utils::RemoveLinks(link.val)) = const int&]’
/home/allan/Codes/expr.cpp:100:41:   required from here
/home/allan/Codes/expr.cpp:88:32: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const Link<int&>&’ from expression of type ‘const int’
     return RemoveLinks(link.val);
                                ^
/home/allan/Codes/expr.cpp:89:1: error: body of constexpr function ‘constexpr decltype (Utils::RemoveLinks(link.val)) Utils::RemoveLinks(const Link<T>&) [with T = int&; decltype (Utils::RemoveLinks(link.val)) = const Link<int&>&]’ not a return-statement
 }
 ^
/home/allan/Codes/expr.cpp: In function ‘constexpr decltype (Utils::RemoveLinks(link.val)) Utils::RemoveLinks(const Link<T>&) [with T = int&; decltype (Utils::RemoveLinks(link.val)) = const int&]’:
/home/allan/Codes/expr.cpp:89:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

while clang 3.3 gives:

```
test.cc:34:12: error: reference to type 'const Link<int &>' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'const int'
return RemoveLinks(link.val);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:46:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Utils::RemoveLinks<Link<int &> >' requested here
std::cout << Utils::RemoveLinks(link) << std::endl;
```

If, however, the namespace `Utils` is removed, then it compiles without errors (both gcc and clang), and execution outputs:

```
Link(Link(10))
10
```

Why defining those template functions (`RemoveLinks`) in a namespace causes such errors?

Comment: Without `constexpr` it compiles and runs fine in VS (`constexpr` is not supported yet). Looks like a gcc bug.

Comment: Interesting. Note that if you remove the namespace and use a qualified name `-> decltype(::RemoveLinks(link.val))`, the error returns. This surely looks like a bug in either two compilers or the C++ standard...

Comment: @catscradle: Does VS do two-phase name lookup yet? :P

Comment: @n.m. No, not as far as I know.

Comment: @catscradle: I'm asking because the error looks like it could be TPL related.

Comment: @catscradle If so, both gcc and clang have the same bug.

Comment: I think the problem is the point of declaration. If I understand it correctly, the name of the second overload is available only *after* the *trailing-return-type*. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1d129d208a4c7a34a871fe182eb5b172-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336)

Answer (score 7):

This problem is a result of an issue with the point of declaration (1) combined with dependent name lookup (2).

**(1)** In the declaration

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto RemoveLinks(const Link<T>& link) -> decltype(RemoveLinks(link.val))
```

the name `RemoveLinks`, or more precisely, this overload of `RemoveLinks`, is only visible *after the complete declarator* according to [basic.scope.pdecl]/1. The *trailing-return-type* is part of the declarator as per [dcl.decl]/4. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744745/420683).

**(2)** In the expression `RemoveLinks(link.val)`, the name `RemoveLinks` is dependent as per [temp.dep]/1, as `link.val` is dependent.

If we now look up how dependent names are resolved, we find [temp.dep.res]:

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> - Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> - Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context and from the definition context.

The first bullet doesn't find the second overload of `RemoveLinks` because of the point of declaration (1). The second one doesn't find the overload because the namespace `Util` is not associated with any argument. This is why putting everything in the global namespace or in the namespace `Util` works as expected ([Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f8c8d16751ad067c061c28b22a0c4afd-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336)).

For the same reason, using a *qualified-id* in the *trailing-return-type* (like `-> decltype(Util::RemoveLinks(link.val))` doesn't help here.

Comment: Why then, if you put everything in the global namespace *and* say `-> decltype(::RemoveLinks(link.val))`, there's still an error? Isn't `RemoveLinks` still a dependent name? If not, why not?

Comment: @n.m. Unfortunately, the Standard is a bit vague about the link between *dependent expressions* (as in *type-dependent expression*) and *dependent names*. If we assume a name is dependent if either 1) the *id-expression* "specifying" that name is dependent (like in `T::some_name`, `T` is dependent, therefore this occurrence of `some_name` is dependent) or 2) it fulfils [temp.dep]/1 (unqualified function call), then the expression `::RemoveLinks(link.val)` is dependent, but the name `RemoveLinks` in it is not, because the *id-expression* here is `::RemoveLinks`.

Comment: @n.m. (continued) This interpretation of the Standard has a weird side effect: e.g. if in the *id-expression* `some_name`, the name `some_name` refers to a nested class, then it is not a dependent name but names a dependent type: It is a dependent type because *name lookup* finds it to be e.g. "a nested class or enumeration that is a member of the current instantiation" [temp.dep.type]/8. That is, (in this reading of the Standard,) types (and expressions) can be dependent even if the names they contain are not.

Comment: "I say we take off and nuke the entire site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure."

Answer (score 2):

I tried compiling the sample code above with GCC 4.8.1, with clang and also Intel icpc and got the same error messages as you.

I am able to get it to successfully compile without trouble if I revise the signature of the template specialization from:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto RemoveLinks(const Link<T>& link) -> decltype(RemoveLinks(link.val))
```

and make the return type as const.  This might cause a compiler warning since the const there is meaningless, but that can be ignored.  I tested it and it works fine for me with gcc, but not icpc or clang:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto RemoveLinks(const Link<T>& link) -> decltype(RemoveLinks(link.val)) const
```

I found the error message (with the original code) from Intel icpc to be the most informative:

code.cc(48): error: template instantiation resulted in unexpected function type of "`auto (const Link<Link<int &>> &)->const int &`" (the meaning of a name may have changed since the template declaration -- the type of the template is "`auto (const Link<T> &)->decltype((<expression>))`")
`std::cout << Utils::RemoveLinks(link) << std::endl;`
                                                ^
          detected during instantiation of "Utils::RemoveLinks" based on template argument `<Link<int &>>` at line 48

Unfortunately, the above answer is more of a workaround for gcc rather than an answer to your question.  I'll update this if I have anything more / better to add.

**EDIT**

It appears that decltype(RemoveLinks(link.val)) is actually following the recursion so that it returns int& rather than Link.

**EDIT #2**

There have been reported bugs in LLVM about crashes caused by decltype recursion problems.  It seems that this is definitely a bug of sorts, but one that seems to be present in multiple implementations of C++.

The problem can be fixed quite easily if you create a an alias for type T in the link struct and have decltype refer to the alias rather than to the return type.  This will eliminate the recursion.  As follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct Link
{
    Link(T&& val) : val(std::forward<T>(val)) {}
    using value_type = T;
    T val;
};
```

And then the RemoveLinks signature is changed accordingly to refer to this alias:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto RemoveLinks(const Link<T>& link) -> decltype(links.value_type)
```

This code successfully builds on all 3 compilers.

I will file some bug reports with the compilers to see if there's anything they can do about it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you mean `decltype(Link<R>::value_type)`? (there is no `links`) Also, did you check that the output of the compiled programs was correct? I tried it and got incorrect output.