# gcc can compile a variadic template while clang cannot

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc, clang

I'm reading some slides named [An Overview of C++11 and C++14](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/tree/master/Presentations/An%20Overview%20of%20C%2B%2B11%20and%20C%2B%2B14) presented by Mr. Leor Zolman. At Page 35 he introduces a way to do the sum operation with `decltype`.

```
struct Sum {
  template <typename T>
  static T sum(T n) {
    return n;
  }
  template <typename T, typename... Args>
  /// static T sum(T n, Args... rest) {
  static auto sum(T n, Args... rest) -> decltype(n + sum(rest...)) {
    return n + sum(rest...);
  }
};
```

When using this snippets for`Sum::sum(1, 2.3, 4, 5);` clang-3.6(from svn) fails to compile this with `-std=c++11`/`-std=c++1y` but gcc-4.9 succeeds. Of course without type deduction for the return type both compile, but that involves type conversion and cannot get the expected result.

So does this indicate a clang bug, or is because of a gcc extension(in respect of c++11 or c++14)?

Comment: Might be a Clang bug, since Clang claims to support all of C++11 and all C++14 draft features.

Comment: @dom0 i also guess so, but don't know where and how this is explained in the draft.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3744400/1147772

Comment: @Drax Strange enough that http://rextester.com/BVNR10123 can get the correct result with c++14, but with `decltype` it can only be put inside the class(add clang doesn't compile).

Comment: @HongxuChen Nope i'm pretty sure what's happening is that your sum template function is not available for calling until its return type is complete, see [T.C.'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26274688/1147772)

Comment: @Drax thanks, now i realized the difference.

Comment: This is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1433

Comment: And http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-closed.html#104

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clang's behavior is correct. This is a GCC bug (and the claim in the presentation is also incorrect). §3.3.2 [basic.scope.pdecl]/p1,6:

> 1 The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its
>   complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its *initializer* (if any),
>   except as noted below.
>
> 6 After the point of declaration of a class member, the member name can
>   be looked up in the scope of its class.

And §3.3.7 [basic.scope.class]/p1 says

> The following rules describe the scope of names declared in classes.
>
> 1) The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only
>   of the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration,
>   but also of all function bodies, default arguments,
>   *exception-specifications*, and *brace-or-equal-initializers* of
>   non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested
>   classes).

*trailing-return-types* are not in that list.

The trailing return type is part of the declarator (§8 [dcl.decl]/p4):

```
declarator:
    ptr-declarator
    noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers trailing-return-type
```

and so the variadic version of `sum` isn't in scope within its own *trailing-return-type* and cannot be found by name lookup.

In C++14, simply use actual return type deduction (and omit the trailing return type). In C++11, you may use a class template instead and a function template that simply forwards:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
struct Sum {
    static auto sum(T n, Args... rest) -> decltype(n + Sum<Args...>::sum(rest...)) {
        return n + Sum<Args...>::sum(rest...);
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Sum<T>{
    static T sum(T n) { return n; }
};

template<class T, class... Args>
auto sum(T n, Args... rest) -> decltype(Sum<T, Args...>::sum(n, rest...)){
    return Sum<T, Args...>::sum(n, rest...);
}
```

Comment: So the code presented is not of standard, and without c++14 return type deduction there seems no *elegant* solution for this, right?

Comment: Off of the top of my head, forwarding to a non-template member function of a template class should work (`template <typename T, typename... Args> auto sum(T n, Args... rest) -> decltype(SumImpl<T, Args...>::impl(n, rest...)) { return SumImpl<T, Args...>::impl(n, rest...); }`, where it is acceptable for `SumImpl<T, Args...>::impl` to use `SumImpl<Args...>::impl`.

Comment: @HongxuChen See my edit. Whether that counts as *elegant*, I don't know.