# Variadic function - determining return type

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

I'm playing with variadic templates and i'm stuck with the following:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
auto sum(T1 a, T2 b) ->decltype(a + b){
    return a + b;
}
template <class T1, class T2, class... T3>
auto sum(T1 a, T2 b, T3... tail) ->decltype(a + b){
    return a + sum(b, tail...);
}
```

Function calls:

```
cout << sum(1, 2, 3, 4) << endl;    // 10 - OK
cout << sum(1.5, 2, 3, 4) << endl;  // 10.5 - OK
cout << sum(1, 2, 3.5, 4) << endl;  // 10 !! wrong result
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, the return type is the type of `a + b`. Here, `a` is `1` and `b` is `2`, so return type is `int`.

Comment: I tried to write decltype(a + tail..) but that does not work..

Comment: @Tracer: "I tried to write decltype(a + tail..) but that does not work.." - By trying this, your question has become equivalent to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274207/gcc-can-compile-a-variadic-template-while-clang-cannot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sum(1, 2, 3.5, 4)
```

The first two arguments are of type `int`. Therefore in the trailing return type, `decltype(a + b)` is `int`, so the result is converted to `int` - and truncated.

Use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
template <class T1, class T2, class... T3>
typename std::common_type<T1, T2, T3...>::type
  sum(T1 a, T2 b, T3... tail) 
{
    return a + sum(b, tail...);
}
```

---

Note that

```
template <class T1, class T2, class... T3>
auto sum(T1 a, T2 b, T3... tail) ->decltype(a + sum(b, tail...))
```

Does not work as this second template isn't known in the trailing-return-type, only the first one. With C++14, return type deduction is possible though:

```
template <class T1, class T2, class... T3>
auto sum(T1 a, T2 b, T3... tail)
{
    return a + sum(b, tail...);
}
```

Comment: In VS 2013 I can use both examples, but clang does not compile the second that uses auto & decltype. So, the second case is C++14 feature?

Comment: The limitation of using `common_type` for this is that it doesn't work with class types.

Comment: @T.C. You're right. I might want to sum up `string`s.

Comment: Note `common_type` does a `decay`, and the C++14 version does not do SFINAE.  Also note that one can specialize `common_type` if need be.

Comment: @Yakk Of course `common_type` does a decay.. but how is that important here? Also, SFINAE isn't used here - I assume that no more function templates called `sum` are declared. Or should that be included in the post, what do you think?

Comment: It is sometimes important that it does a `decay`, but here we are sort of abusing it anyhow.  (`int a,b; (test?a:b)=3` works, but `common_type` will say it won't).  Because we are using it as a proxy for `+`, the odds that the reference type of `_?a:b` and `a+b` are the same would be a coincidence anyhow.  So not important. SFINAE matters in that the error message you get is different, and someone else could have a `sum` function somewhere.  Imagine `sum( Iterator a, Iterator b )` which is a pretty natural function: your `sum` causes a build break if it is also visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace details{
  template<template<class,class>class binary_result, class T, class...Ts>
  struct nary_result{using type=T};
  template<template<class,class>class binary_result, class T0, class T1, class...Ts>
  struct nary_result<binary_result, T0,T1,Ts...>:
    nary_result<binary_result,binary_result<T0,T1>,Ts...>
  {};
}
template<template<class,class>class binary_result, class...Ts>
using nary_result=typename details::nary_result<binary_result,Ts...>::type;

template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
using binary_sum_result = decltype(std::declval<Lhs>()+std::declval<Rhs>());

template<class...Ts>
using sum_result=nary_result<binary_sum_result,Ts...>;
```

should do the trick.

Maybe add a decay.