# Is clang right to reject a template call with a trailing decltype return type depending on one of its overloads?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overload-resolution, trailing-return-type

I was surprised to see that clang failed to compile the following c++11 code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct A {};

template<class T>
struct B : A<T> { T x; };

template<class T>
const typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& add_const(T&& x) { return x; }

template<class T>
T& cast_away_const(const T& x) { return const_cast<T&>(x); }

template<class T>
const B<T>& downcast(const A<T>& x) { return static_cast<const B<T>&>(x); }

template<class T>
auto downcast(A<T>& a) ->
decltype(cast_away_const(downcast(add_const(a)))) {
    return cast_away_const(downcast(add_const(a)));
}

int main() {
    B<int> b;
    b.x = 42;
    A<int>& a = b;
    B<int>& b_again = downcast(a);
    return b_again.x;
}
```

To be more accurate, clang 3.7.1 complains about a long template instantiation chain, behaving as if the instantiation of `auto downcast(A<T>& a) -> /*...*/` with `T=int` required the instantiation of itself.
clang 5.0.0 or 6.0.0 merely crashes (!).
Both gcc and msvc accept.

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/f1obMv)

Now, clang-5.0.0 crashing is obviously a bug, but clang-3.7.1 error made some sense so…
**Is that code legal in the first place?**

Let me emphasize I'm asking for whether this code is legal, not for a workaround (an easy workaround would be to split `overload` in `overload` and `overload_const`, have the later handle only const references and have the former call the later).

I could find the following somewhat related point of contention between clang and gcc [(trailing return type using decltype with a variadic template function, SO link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744400/trailing-return-type-using-decltype-with-a-variadic-template-function) alongside with this similar question whose answer cites the standard [(gcc can compile a variadic template while clang cannot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274207/gcc-can-compile-a-variadic-template-while-clang-cannot?noredirect=1&lq=1)
I'm however not sure the exact same argument applies here (as `downcast` should refer to a previously declared overload and not itself in the trailing return type).

Comment: It is really a bug in clang, when tried to compile on a mac (with clang installed as a default with Xcode), it states that this must be sent as a bug report

Comment: @user the crash is a bug, doesn't mean the code is valid.

Answer (score 2):

So the first thing is that `downcast` can be found via ADL on `A<T>` as it is in an associated namespace.

So here:

```
template<class T>
auto downcast(A<T>& a) ->
decltype(cast_away_const(downcast(add_const(a))))
```

itself must be considered when determining the return type of itself.  If it was in a different namespace, it would not be permitted to consider itself as a possible overload candidate.

So that is an easy solution; move both overloads into `details`.  Maybe have a helper in the same namespace  `A`  that forwards to the details version.

Obviously msvc and gcc notice that the `const&` overload will be a better pick before fully re-evaluating the return type of the non-const version.

```
details {
  template<class T>
  const B<T>& downcast(const A<T>& x) { return static_cast<const B<T>&>(x); }

  template<class T>
  auto downcast(A<T>& a) ->
  decltype(cast_away_const(details::downcast(add_const(a)))) {
    return cast_away_const(details::downcast(add_const(a)));
  }
}
template<class X,
  std::enable_if_t< /* A<T> is a base of X for some T */,  bool> =true
>
auto downcast(X&& x)
-> decltype(details::downcast(std::forward<X>(x)))
{ return details::downcast(std::forward<X>(x)); }
```

I do not know if clang is right to treat the code as an ill formed program or not.

Comment: Huh, second overload *still* is in the *same* namespace as the first one, so shouldn't itself *still* be considered???

Comment: Your mention of `downcast` being found by ADL in the trailing return type indeed clarifies things! However I'm not sure I should accept that answer as it doesn't explicitly tell whether the code really is illegal (but upvoted!).

Comment: Peeked into C++17, §16.3 (and especially 16.3.2), but did not find any valuable clues. Some thoughts, though: Return type is not relevant for overload resolution, so would be possible to ignore it/assume void. Thus itself at least *could* be part of the "viable function list". On the other hand, is it fully declared without the trailing return type? Can functions partially declared this way take part in overload resolution at all? Assuming they are partially declared only and are not taken into account: GCC is right. Assuming they *are* taken into account, then if we *can* ignore the ...

Comment: ... return type there is no need to fully evaluate the function until we decide which overload to use for the return type, thus again GCC would be right then (and failure would only occure if we needed to select itself as "best viable function"). If we cannot ignore, then CLANG would be right rejecting the code.

Comment: @Aconcagua The return type is part of overload resolution in that it is needed to know if you should remove the overload from consideration.  However, you can know *before* you calculate the return type that *it wouldn't be chosen*.  It is *possible* that gcc and mvsc optimize around that return type calculation by saying "we don't need to know this", while clang doesn't, and the program is ill-formed but the opimization of gcc/msvc makes it not notice.  An optimization that is valid on all well formed programs is a valid optimization if ill-formedness is no diagnostic required.

Comment: @Yakk Ah, I see, e. g. `std::enable_if` in the return type might disqualify some potential overloads... So that point for CLANG at least. Remains open the point of partially declared functions, though. A function not declared (at all) cannot take part in OR, sure. But now does a function count as declared or not, as long as the return type is not yet known?